# java for loop executes too fast gives System.currentTimeMillis() duplicate

Tags: java, random, for-loop, unique

Java: I have a problem using System.currentTimeMillis() function

i am using System.currentTimeMillis() to generate unique values in foor loop problem is loop executes too fast and System.currentTimeMillis() gives me duplicate values.

How can i generate for sure unique values.

```
for(int a=0;a<=10;a++){
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis())
}
```

I also tried following but it is also not generaet to generate unique number

```
System.currentTimeMillis()+Math.random()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why don't you use `System.nanoTime()` instead?

Comment: If i execute more at more fast machine are there any chances to make it duplicate value?

Comment: From the JavaDoc: "No guarantees are made about how frequently values change." You could **easily** run into an implementation that doesn't change any more frequently than `currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: I agree with @Perception that you shouldn't use system timer for unique number generation : even if your system is slow enough not to generate the same ID per each iteration, what happens if you have this running on multi-processor architectures, where 2 threads could concurrently run at the same time and end up with the same id's. How about using something like this instead: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56

Comment: @ Faisal I get duplicate values

Comment: I agree if specially comparing in a loop we should not i like the idea have random UUID

Comment: I am going to use UUID as random image name will it ever UUID chars exceed file name chars ?

Comment: Timestamps and random numbers cannot be used if you require uniqueness.   It's mathematically incorrect.  You have to use UUID, a static counter, or a cluster-singleton counter of some sort.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you use a UUID library to generate unique identifiers (already there in the JDK http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html).

Or for a more simple approach: append a static counter

Answer (score 2):

The answer is obvious - get a slower computer! Well, that or use System.nanoTime as described right here on SO - [System.currentTimeMillis vs System.nanoTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime). But seriously, you shouldn't be using time as unique number generator unless you absolutely have to.

The problem with using the system time of course being that:

- The time returned by your system
  calls is rounded up to a higher
  degree of precision than the actual
  CPU clock time. If your ID generation
  code runs faster than this degree of
  precision then you will have
  collision.
- If your code is distributed and each
  unit of work is generating ID's then
  you run into the possibility of ID
  collision as the separate CPU's or
  CPU core's allocate ID's using their
  independent clocks.
- In libraries like Java that are
  actually returning the system time
  based off a user settable property
  you run into a higher chance of
  multiple ID collision anytime the
  date is reset to some period in the
  past, for whatever reason.

A very good alternative to generating unique identifiers is to utilize the not-so-ironically named [Universally Unique Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). There is a multiple implementations in various languages, for Java 5 and higher you can use the [UUID](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class.

**Edit**: To add some useful information about UUID.

Comment: +1 for "you shouldn't be using time as unique number generator unless you absolutely have to."

Comment: +1 True, it's better to use a more robust algorithm to generate unique values. What if, for example the application runs on multiple computers, each generating their own values?

Comment: +1 Use UUID, a static counter (single JVM) or a cluster singleton counter (a database or a fancy cluster singleton).

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach is wrong, if this is a requirement.

Theoretically, no matter how fine-grained your timer, a machine *might* execute it in less time than the timer's granularity.  It's not correct in a technical sense to depend on this being true.

Or looking at it another way - *why* do you need these values to be unique (what are you using them for)?  If you really want them to be a measure of the time it was executed, then you ought to be happy that two iterations that happened within the same millisecond got the same value.

Have you considered using a static, monotonous counter to assign IDs to each iteration that are unique within each execution (`AtomicLong` is great for this)?  Something like the following is very easy and has no concurrency issues:

```
public class YourClass {

    private static final AtomicLong COUNTER = new AtomicLong();

    private static nextId() { return COUNTER.getAndIncrement(); }

    // Rest of the class, which calls nextId() when it needs an identifier
}
```

If you need the timing info *and* uniqueness, then that's two separate requirements, so why not have a composite key made up of the time *and* an arbitrary unique ID?

Comment: Yes, the approach is wrong.   Neither random numbers nor the system time can guarantee unique numbers.   The static counter here will work well for single-JVM systems.   It will not work in a cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Andrej's solution, but combining a timer and a counter so your numbers shouldn't repeat if you restart your application.

```
public enum IdGenerator {
    ;

    private static final AtomicLong COUNTER = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis()*1000);

    public static long nextId() { return COUNTER.getAndIncrement(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to still use your method, you could do:

```
for(int a=0;a<=10;a++){
    Thread.sleep(1);
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis())
}
```

Explicitly making your CPU slower.

Answer (score 0):

try Math.random()*System.currentTimeMillis()

here is a sample outcome

```
4.1140390961236145E11,
4.405289623285403E11,
6.743938910583776E11,
2.0358542930175632E11,
1.2561886548511025E12,
8.629388909268735E11,
1.158038719369676E12,
2.5899667030405692E11,
7.815373208372445E11,
1.0887553507952611E12,
3.947241572203385E11,
1.6723200316764807E11,
1.3071550541162832E12,
2.079941126415029E11,
1.304485187296599E12,
3.5889095083604164E10,
1.3230275106525027E11,
6.484641777434403E11,
5.109822261418748E11,
1.2291750972884333E12,
8.972865957307518E11,
4.022754883048088E11,
7.997154244301389E11,
1.139245696210086E12,
2.633248409945871E11,
8.699957189419155E11,
9.487098785390422E11,
1.1645067228773708E12,
1.5274939161218903E11,
4.8470112347655725E11,
8.749120668472205E11,
2.435762445513599E11,
5.62884487469596E11,
1.1412787212758718E12,
1.0724213377031631E12,
3.1388106597100226E11,
1.1405727247661633E12,
1.2464739913912961E12,
3.2771161059896655E11,
1.2102869787179648E12,
1.168806596179512E12,
5.871383012375131E11,
1.2765757372075571E12,
5.868323434343102E11,
9.887351363037219E11,
5.392282944314777E11,
1.1926033895638833E12,
6.867917070018711E11,
1.1682059242674294E12,
2.4442056772643954E11,
1.1250254537683052E12,
8.875186600355891E10,
3.46331811747409E11,
1.127077925657995E12,
7.056541627184794E11,
1.308631075052609E12,
7.7875319089675E11,
5.52717019956371E11,
7.727797813063546E11,
6.177219592063667E11,
2.9448141585070874E11,
9.617992263836586E11,
6.762500987418107E11,
1.1954995292124463E12,
1.0741763597148225E12,
1.9915919731861673E11,
9.507720563185525E11,
1.1009594810160002E12,
4.1381256571745465E11,
2.2526550777831213E11,
2.5919816802026202E11,
3.8453225321522577E11,
3.796715779825083E11,
6.512277843921505E10,
1.0483456960599313E12,
1.0725956186588704E11,
5.701504883615902E11,
9.085583903150035E11,
1.2764816439306753E12,
1.033783414053437E12,
1.188379914238302E12,
6.42733442524156E11,
3.911345432964901E11,
7.936334657654698E11,
1.4473479058272617E11,
1.2030471387183499E12,
5.900668555531211E11,
8.078992189613184E11,
1.2004364275316113E12,
1.250275098717202E12,
2.856556784847933E11,
1.9118298791320355E11,
5.4291847597892596E11,
3.9527733898520874E11,
6.384539941791654E11,
1.2812873515441786E11,
6.325269269733575E9,
5.403119000792323E11,
8.023708335126083E11,
3.761680594623883E10,
1.2641772837928888E11,
```

Comment: Well why not just use Math.random() if all you need is a unique number then?  The notion of time has been lost so all you have are (hopefully) unique numbers.

Comment: Basic mathematics: A random number sequence is not the same thing as a unique number sequence.   Multiplying by the system time might change the distribution a little, but it's still not unique.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [UUID](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) as well...

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion

```
    long id = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //do your work
        id++;
    }
```

Comment: if it a suggestion comment it, in case it is an answer keep it here please