# How to profile methods in Scala?

Tags: function, scala, profiling, aspect

What is a standard way of profiling Scala method calls?

What I need are hooks around a method, using which I can use to start and stop Timers.

In Java I use aspect programming, aspectJ, to define the methods to be profiled and inject bytecode to achieve the same.

Is there a more natural way in Scala, where I can define a bunch of functions to be called before and after a function without losing any static typing in the process?

Comment: If AspectJ plays nicely with Scala, use AspectJ. Why reinvent the wheel? The answers above which use custom flow control fail to achieve the basic requirements of AOP since to use them you need to modify your code. These could also be of interest: http://java.dzone.com/articles/real-world-scala-managing-cros http://blog.fakod.eu/2010/07/26/cross-cutting-concerns-in-scala/

Comment: - https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/microbenchmarking-scala-with-jmh/
 - https://github.com/wadejensen/sbt-jmh-example
 - https://github.com/ktoso/sbt-jmh

Comment: What are you interested in?  Do  you want  to know how long a certain method takes in the production environment. Then you should look metrics libraries and not roll measurement yourself as in the accepted answer. If you want to investigate which code variant is faster "in general", i.e. in your development environment, use  sbt-jmh as presented below.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Do you want to do this without changing the code that you want to measure timings for? If you don't mind changing the code, then you could do something like this:

```
def time[R](block: => R): R = {
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    val result = block    // call-by-name
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time: " + (t1 - t0) + "ns")
    result
}

// Now wrap your method calls, for example change this...
val result = 1 to 1000 sum

// ... into this
val result = time { 1 to 1000 sum }
```

Comment: This is neat, can I do the same thing without any code change?

Comment: Not automatically with this solution; how would Scala know what you'd want to time?

Comment: This is not strictly true - you can automatically wrap things in the REPL

Comment: some sort of implicit import or some annotation?

Comment: Almost perfect, but you must react upon possible exceptions too. Calculate `t1` within a `finally` clause

Comment: You can add a label to your prints with some currying: `def time[R](label: String)(block: => R): R = {` then add the label to the `println`

Comment: A version with more human-readable output (even if this comment format isn't very human readable!) `val start = java.time.Instant.now()
    val result = block // call-by-name
    val stop = java.time.Instant.now()
    val d = java.time.Duration.between(start, stop);
    println(s"Elapsed time: ${d.toMinutesPart()} mins ${d.toSecondsPart()} secs ${d.toMillisPart()} ms (${d.toMillis()}ms)")`

Answer (score 35):

In addition to Jesper's answer, you can automatically wrap method invocations in the REPL:

```
scala> def time[R](block: => R): R = {
   | val t0 = System.nanoTime()
   | val result = block
   | println("Elapsed time: " + (System.nanoTime - t0) + "ns")
   | result
   | }
time: [R](block: => R)R
```

Now - let's wrap anything in this

```
scala> :wrap time
wrap: no such command.  Type :help for help.
```

OK - we need to be in power mode

```
scala> :power
** Power User mode enabled - BEEP BOOP SPIZ **
** :phase has been set to 'typer'.          **
** scala.tools.nsc._ has been imported      **
** global._ and definitions._ also imported **
** Try  :help,  vals.<tab>,  power.<tab>    **
```

Wrap away

```
scala> :wrap time
Set wrapper to 'time'

scala> BigDecimal("1.456")
Elapsed time: 950874ns
Elapsed time: 870589ns
Elapsed time: 902654ns
Elapsed time: 898372ns
Elapsed time: 1690250ns
res0: scala.math.BigDecimal = 1.456
```

I have no idea why that printed stuff out 5 times

Update as of 2.12.2:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

package wrappers { object wrap { def apply[A](a: => A): A = { println("running...") ; a } }}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.


scala> $intp.setExecutionWrapper("wrappers.wrap")

scala> 42
running...
res2: Int = 42
```

Comment: To spare anyone the trouble of wondering now, the `:wrap` feature [was removed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-user/cE-z6fxkq0U/EszYr_19qgMJ) from the REPL :-\

Answer (score 29):

This what I use:

```
import System.nanoTime
def profile[R](code: => R, t: Long = nanoTime) = (code, nanoTime - t)

// usage:
val (result, time) = profile { 
  /* block of code to be profiled*/ 
}

val (result2, time2) = profile methodToBeProfiled(foo)
```

Answer (score 25):

There are [three benchmarking libraries for Scala](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Tools+and+Libraries#ToolsandLibraries-Benchmarking) that you can avail of.

Since the URLs on the linked site are likely to change, I am pasting the relevant content below.

1. [SPerformance](https://github.com/jsuereth/sperformance) - Performance Testing framework aimed at automagically comparing performance tests and working inside Simple Build Tool.
2. [scala-benchmarking-template](https://github.com/sirthias/scala-benchmarking-template) - SBT template project for creating Scala (micro-)benchmarks based on Caliper.
3. [Metrics](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics) - Capturing JVM- and application-level metrics. So you know what's going on

Answer (score 7):

The recommended approach to benchmarking Scala code is via [sbt-jmh](https://github.com/ktoso/sbt-jmh)

> "Trust no one, bench everything." - sbt plugin for JMH (Java
>   Microbenchmark Harness)

This approach is taken by many of the major Scala projects, for example,

- [Scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/b6c6486f7105c76712bd68f5652af0cb0d4af908/project/plugins.sbt#L32) programming language itself
- [Dotty](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/3d26c53f65d6967cc368f16a7899947d593cf08e/project/plugins.sbt#L13) (Scala 3)
- [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/424569f9c7dd7e99f6a6d1b72980db00b75627cb/project/plugins.sbt#L8) library for functional programming
- [Metals](https://github.com/scalameta/metals/blob/b025f2d4aa8b447366d6ee5e88817a45e6b9d03a/project/plugins.sbt#L2) language server for IDEs

Simple wrapper timer based on `System.nanoTime` is [not a reliable method](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/) of benchmarking:

> `System.nanoTime` is as bad as `String.intern` now: you can use it,
>   but use it wisely. The latency, granularity, and scalability effects
>   introduced by timers may and will affect your measurements if done
>   without proper rigor. This is one of the many reasons why
>   `System.nanoTime` should be abstracted from the users by benchmarking
>   frameworks

Furthermore, considerations such as [JIT warmup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198278/why-does-the-jvm-require-warmup), garbage collection, system-wide events, etc. might [introduce unpredictability](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22604185/5205022) into measurements:

> Tons of effects need to be mitigated, including warmup, dead code
>   elimination, forking, etc. Luckily, JMH already takes care of many
>   things, and has bindings for both Java and Scala.

Based on [Travis Brown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59600699/5205022) here is an [example](https://github.com/mario-galic/scala-jmh-benchmark-example) of how to setup JMH benchmark for Scala

1. Add jmh to `project/plugins.sbt`

   ```
   addSbtPlugin("pl.project13.scala" % "sbt-jmh" % "0.3.7")
   ```
2. Enable jmh plugin in `build.sbt`

   ```
   enablePlugins(JmhPlugin)
   ```
3. Add to `src/main/scala/bench/VectorAppendVsListPreppendAndReverse.scala`

   ```
   package bench

   import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations._

   @State(Scope.Benchmark)
   @BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.AverageTime))
   class VectorAppendVsListPreppendAndReverse {
     val size = 1_000_000
     val input = 1 to size

     @Benchmark def vectorAppend: Vector[Int] = 
       input.foldLeft(Vector.empty[Int])({ case (acc, next) => acc.appended(next)})

     @Benchmark def listPrependAndReverse: List[Int] = 
       input.foldLeft(List.empty[Int])({ case (acc, next) => acc.prepended(next)}).reverse
   }
   ```
4. Execute benchmark with

   ```
   sbt "jmh:run -i 10 -wi 10 -f 2 -t 1 bench.VectorAppendVsListPreppendAndReverse"
   ```

The results are

```
Benchmark                                                   Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
VectorAppendVsListPreppendAndReverse.listPrependAndReverse  avgt   20  0.024 ± 0.001   s/op
VectorAppendVsListPreppendAndReverse.vectorAppend           avgt   20  0.130 ± 0.003   s/op
```

which seems to indicate prepending to a `List` and then reversing it at the end is order of magnitude faster than keep appending to a `Vector`.

Answer (score 6):

`testing.Benchmark` might be useful.

```
scala> def testMethod {Thread.sleep(100)}
testMethod: Unit

scala> object Test extends testing.Benchmark {
     |   def run = testMethod
     | }
defined module Test

scala> Test.main(Array("5"))
$line16.$read$$iw$$iw$Test$     100     100     100     100     100
```

Comment: Be aware that testing.Benchmark is @deprecated("This class will be removed.", "2.10.0").

Answer (score 6):

I use a technique that's easy to move around in code blocks. The crux is that the same exact line starts and ends the timer - so it is really a simple copy and paste. The other nice thing is that you get to define what the timing means to you as a string, all in that same line.

Example usage:

```
Timelog("timer name/description")
//code to time
Timelog("timer name/description")
```

The code:

```
object Timelog {

  val timers = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, Long]

  //
  // Usage: call once to start the timer, and once to stop it, using the same timer name parameter
  //
  def timer(timerName:String) = {
    if (timers contains timerName) {
      val output = s"$timerName took ${(System.nanoTime() - timers(timerName)) / 1000 / 1000} milliseconds"
      println(output) // or log, or send off to some performance db for analytics
    }
    else timers(timerName) = System.nanoTime()
  }
```

Pros:

- no need to wrap code as a block or manipulate within lines
- can easily move the start and end of the timer among code lines when being exploratory

Cons:

- less shiny for utterly functional code
- obviously this object leaks map entries if you do not "close" timers,
  e.g. if your code doesn't get to the second invocation for a given timer start.

Comment: This is great, but shouldn't the usage be: `Timelog.timer("timer name/description")`?

Answer (score 6):

[ScalaMeter](http://scalameter.github.io/) is a nice library to perform benchmarking in Scala

Below is a simple example

```
import org.scalameter._

def sumSegment(i: Long, j: Long): Long = (i to j) sum

val (a, b) = (1, 1000000000)

val execution_time = measure { sumSegment(a, b) }
```

If you execute above code snippet in Scala Worksheet you get the running time in milliseconds

```
execution_time: org.scalameter.Quantity[Double] = 0.260325 ms
```

Answer (score 5):

I took the solution from Jesper and added some aggregation to it on multiple run of the same code

```
def time[R](block: => R) = {
    def print_result(s: String, ns: Long) = {
      val formatter = java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance
      println("%-16s".format(s) + formatter.format(ns) + " ns")
    }

    var t0 = System.nanoTime()
    var result = block    // call-by-name
    var t1 = System.nanoTime()

    print_result("First Run", (t1 - t0))

    var lst = for (i <- 1 to 10) yield {
      t0 = System.nanoTime()
      result = block    // call-by-name
      t1 = System.nanoTime()
      print_result("Run #" + i, (t1 - t0))
      (t1 - t0).toLong
    }

    print_result("Max", lst.max)
    print_result("Min", lst.min)
    print_result("Avg", (lst.sum / lst.length))
}
```

Suppose you want to time two functions `counter_new` and `counter_old`, the following is the usage:

```
scala> time {counter_new(lst)}
First Run       2,963,261,456 ns
Run #1          1,486,928,576 ns
Run #2          1,321,499,030 ns
Run #3          1,461,277,950 ns
Run #4          1,299,298,316 ns
Run #5          1,459,163,587 ns
Run #6          1,318,305,378 ns
Run #7          1,473,063,405 ns
Run #8          1,482,330,042 ns
Run #9          1,318,320,459 ns
Run #10         1,453,722,468 ns
Max             1,486,928,576 ns
Min             1,299,298,316 ns
Avg             1,407,390,921 ns

scala> time {counter_old(lst)}
First Run       444,795,051 ns
Run #1          1,455,528,106 ns
Run #2          586,305,699 ns
Run #3          2,085,802,554 ns
Run #4          579,028,408 ns
Run #5          582,701,806 ns
Run #6          403,933,518 ns
Run #7          562,429,973 ns
Run #8          572,927,876 ns
Run #9          570,280,691 ns
Run #10         580,869,246 ns
Max             2,085,802,554 ns
Min             403,933,518 ns
Avg             797,980,787 ns
```

Hopefully this is helpful

Answer (score 3):

I like the simplicity of @wrick's answer, but also wanted:

- the profiler handles looping (for consistency and convenience)
- more accurate timing (using nanoTime)
- time per iteration (not total time of all iterations)
- just return ns/iteration - not a tuple

This is achieved here:

```
def profile[R] (repeat :Int)(code: => R, t: Long = System.nanoTime) = { 
  (1 to repeat).foreach(i => code)
  (System.nanoTime - t)/repeat
}
```

For even more accuracy, a simple modification allows a JVM Hotspot warmup loop (not timed) for timing small snippets:

```
def profile[R] (repeat :Int)(code: => R) = {  
  (1 to 10000).foreach(i => code)   // warmup
  val start = System.nanoTime
  (1 to repeat).foreach(i => code)
  (System.nanoTime - start)/repeat
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it would be best to write it as a comment

Comment: @nedim The solution is given to the question - a wrapper for anything you want to time. Any functions the OP would want to call can be placed in the wrapper, or in the block that calls his functions so that he "can define a bunch of functions to be called before and after a function without losing any static typing"

Comment: You are right. Sorry, I must have overlooked the code. When my edit gets reviewed I can undo the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.currentTimeMillis`:

```
def time[R](block: => R): R = {
    val t0 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val result = block    // call-by-name
    val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println("Elapsed time: " + (t1 - t0) + "ms")
    result
}
```

Usage:

```
time{
    //execute somethings here, like methods, or some codes.
}
```

nanoTime will show you `ns`, so it will hard to see. So I suggest that you can use currentTimeMillis instead of it.

Comment: Nanoseconds being hard to see is a poor reason for picking between the two. There are some important differences besides resolution. For one, currentTimeMillis can change and even go backwards during clock adjustments that the OS performs periodically. Another is that nanoTime may not be thread safe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime

Answer (score 1):

While standing on the shoulders of giants...

A solid 3rd-party library would be more ideal, but if you need something quick and std-library based, following variant provides:

- Repetitions
- *Last result wins* for multiple repetitions
- Total time and average time for multiple repetitions
- Removes the need for time/instant provider as a param

.

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.{postfixOps, implicitConversions}

package object profile {

  def profile[R](code: => R): R = profileR(1)(code)

  def profileR[R](repeat: Int)(code: => R): R = {
    require(repeat > 0, "Profile: at least 1 repetition required")

    val start = Deadline.now

    val result = (1 until repeat).foldLeft(code) { (_: R, _: Int) => code }

    val end = Deadline.now

    val elapsed = ((end - start) / repeat)

    if (repeat > 1) {
      println(s"Elapsed time: $elapsed averaged over $repeat repetitions; Total elapsed time")

      val totalElapsed = (end - start)

      println(s"Total elapsed time: $totalElapsed")
    }
    else println(s"Elapsed time: $elapsed")

    result
  }
}
```

Also worth noting you can use the `Duration.toCoarsest` method to convert to the biggest time unit possible, although I am not sure how friendly this is with minor time difference between runs e.g.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_60).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

scala> import scala.language.{postfixOps, implicitConversions}
import scala.language.{postfixOps, implicitConversions}

scala> 1000.millis
res0: scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration = 1000 milliseconds

scala> 1000.millis.toCoarsest
res1: scala.concurrent.duration.Duration = 1 second

scala> 1001.millis.toCoarsest
res2: scala.concurrent.duration.Duration = 1001 milliseconds

scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding on => method with name & seconds

```
profile[R](block: => R,methodName : String): R = {
    val n = System.nanoTime()
    val result = block
    val n1 = System.nanoTime()
    println(s"Elapsed time: ${TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(n1 - n,TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)}ms - MethodName: ${methodName}")
    result
  }
```