# Scala: How to define a function whose input is (f, args) and whose output is f(args)?

Tags: scala, generics, lazy-evaluation

How can you define a function `myEval(f, args)` in Scala which takes as input another function `f` and arguments `args` and whose output is `f(args)`?

I don't want `myEval` to have any prior knowledge about the arity or argument types of `f`.

Why is this useful? It is one way to solve the problem of implementing a generic `timeMyFunction(f, args)` method. If there's a way to do this by some sort of lazy val construction, that would also be interesting.

**Edit**: The better way to implement a timing method is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160001/how-to-profile-methods-in-scala/9160068#9160068). By calling `timeMyFunction( { f(args) } )`, the function call is wrapped in an anonymous function `Unit => Unit`. So `timeMyFunction` only needs to take 0-arity functions.

**Edit 2**: See Dirk's answer for what is perhaps a more efficient way which avoids an anonymous function by passing `f` by reference.

So my justification for the question is now purely my Scala education.

Comment: Not much an answer, but usually timeMyFunction [is written in a bit different way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9160068/298389) (and yes, it will work for functions with arbitrary arity)

Comment: My attempts at writing a timeMyFunction were based off the link you post, but you have to make a different version for every arity, at least in my naive way of doing it.

Comment: [No, you don't](http://scalafiddle.net/console/7fcc48d22804dbbe9b66b607d51389d4)

Comment: instead of specifying function and arguments for it, you should provide a whole block(e.g: instead of  `timeMyFunction(f, args)`, `timeMyFunction(f(args))` where timeMyFunction signature is as in the link provided by om-nom-nom)

Comment: Thanks! So it looks like I am wrapping f in an anonymous function which takes no arguments, and then I can use the time function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Scala standard library isn't going to help you generalize over arity in most cases, but [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) is perfect for this. Here's how you could write your function in Shapeless 1.2.4:

```
import shapeless._

def foo[F, P <: Product, A <: HList, R](f: F, p: P)(implicit
  fl: FnHListerAux[F, A => R],
  pl: HListerAux[P, A]
): R = fl(f)(pl(p))
```

And then:

```
scala> foo((i: Int, s: String) => s * i, (3, "a"))
res0: String = aaa
```

It looks complicated, but essentially you're just saying that you need evidence that a function `f` of some arbitrary arity can be converted to a single-argument function from a heterogeneous list `A` to the result `R`, and that the tuple `P` can be converted to a heterogeneous list of the same type.

Comment: It makes sense, and the shapeless library looks very powerful, but I don't see why Scala doesn't consider the arguments of a function to be a tuple, e.g., that all functions have type Function[Tuple]?

Comment: Yep, that's a good question. I wish Scala had followed OCaml, Haskell, etc. in that respect.

Comment: @expz: Unifying parameter lists and tuples has been an Martin Odersky's wish list for a long time, but it is a) low priority and b) very hard to pull off in a way that is both backwards-compatible and doesn't hurt platform integration. For example, how would Java see an overloaded Scala method, if all overloads just take a tuple?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using pass-by-name would be:

```
def timeIt[T](thunk: =>T): T = {
    // ... set-up the timer 
    val answer: T = thunk
    // ... evaluate the result of the timer
    answer  // in case, you need the result and want the timing to
}           // happen just as a side-effect

timeIt(someFunction(someArg1, ...))
```

Though this looks as if it would call `someFunction` directly, it does not, since `timeIt` takes the argument "by name", i.e., the scala compiler generates a hidden closure, which performs the call, when the actual value is needed in `timeIt` itself.

This variant may introduce some timing noise due to the overhead of the "pass-by-name" convention.