# Why first call is so long?

Tags: java, jit

I found that first call of some function take too long time.
Here my simple test:

```
public class MainTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            k += doWork(i);
            System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - start);
        }
        System.out.println(k);    
    }

    public static long doWork(long var) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            var += i;
        }
        return var;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
820521
283961
292514
259442
88952
86100
82965
81539
74126
29651
```

Can you give me some versions about why it's happening? Or some resources where I can find the answer. It can be connected with JIT, but I'am not sure about this.

I know that **nanotime** is not correct for testing. I try JMH:

```
# Warmup Iteration   1: 179791124,395 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   2: 183962412,435 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   3: 284320650,805 ops/s
```

Comment: The call to `nanoTime` probably takes longer than the code you are testing...

Comment: In fact I just simplified code. I found this behavior when integrate groovy script in runtime and then just try the code above - same behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: No, of course not. Why you think it's duplicate? I'am not trying to benchmark at all !

Comment: It is close to a duplicate because your first problem is that you dont understand how to generate meaningful numbers. Beyond that: I appreciate the quick accept!

Comment: When you say **meaningful** what you mean? :) 
I did not try **to generate meaningful numbers**. I interested why I get such results.

Comment: Well. You intend to draw conclusions from the numbers you generate. You ask "why do I observe xyz"; but what if your *observation* is not significant. But well, I think we all got something out of this.

Comment: Yeah, I got your point. For these reason I used JMH(just in case). And test above is just simple example, just to explain the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two aspects here:

- Your benchmark is basically flawed and screwed up. You want to read  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java).
- Yes, the JIT needs a **[warm up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198278/why-does-the-jvm-require-warmup)**.

Simply spoken: at runtime, the JIT observes what your code is doing. It applies **heuristics** that trigger optimizations calls. Thus: don't expected deterministic behavior. It is *hard* to get to really meaningful numbers.

In order to get more reliable results, you will have to *dramatically* improve the quality of your "measurement" process.

Comment: Tbh, this question is a duplicate of your link, just like for the NPE questions.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the answer. Helped link to warm-up. It's not benchmark at all. I did not try to make **accurate** measurements. I get that behaviour and try to find out why this is so.