# First call to `ArraysKt.contains` is slow

Tags: kotlin

Consider this:

```
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis

fun main() {
  // Uncomment, and make it >=2 elements will make [timeInMillis] 0.
  // Changing [setOf] to [arrayOf] doesn't help.
  // setOf(1, 2)

  val timeInMillis = measureTimeMillis {
    3 in arrayOf(4)
  }
  println("$timeInMillis ms")
}
```

I believe `3 in arrayOf(4)` is equivalent to the `ArraysKt.contains(new Integer[]{4}, 3);` Java code.

For some reason, on linux in the JVM, `timeInMillis` can take up to 30ms. I was led to this when benchmarking the equivalent on Android, where on a Pixel 2 device, it can take up to 90 ms. These numbers seem to be quite large considering the workload.

My guess is that there's some sort of lazy initialization going on in Kotlin stdlib which causes this. How do I find out more about what's going on?

Comment: what is the precision of `measureTimeMillis`? My guess is that it depends on JVM implementation, and that your OS only gives cpu cycles in 30ms. I see the same, when I try to measure time intervals in Java with instances of Calendar, instead of using `System.nanoTime()`. According to the source of `measureTileMillis`: `System.currentTimeMillis()` is used, which is not precise enough for small timespans. https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/80cce1dc5280eb9135390270c8644a7b8d198071/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/system/Timing.kt#L16 use `measureNanoTime` instead

Comment: After some experimenting around. I think this is due to the JVM warming up. The Kotlin classes won't be loaded until you first use them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198278/why-does-the-jvm-require-warmup

Comment: Your test is in no way specialized enough to perform bench marking at such small workload.

Comment: You cannot draw any conclusion from this test. [Microbenchmarking is hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) - there is a lot to learn about up front. Usually, we rely on tools like JMH which help you avoid the common pitfalls of microbenchmarking. In this specific case, the time resolution is too small, there are not enough iterations to have a relevant measurement, and there is no JVM warmup (which throws any measurement out of the window, because the measurement will be affected by loading classes, and won't benefit from the JIT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My guess is that there's some sort of lazy initialization going on in Kotlin stdlib which causes this.

There is indeed lazy initialisation, and this is not about Kotlin, but the JVM. This is the way the JVM loads classes. You can use the `-verbose:class` JVM option to find out which classes are initialised.

```
println("Measure Start!")
val timeInMillis = measureNanoTime {
    3 in arrayOf(4)
}
println("Measure End!")
println("$timeInMillis ns")
```

Running this on my macOS machine with IntelliJ with `-verbose:class` prints (showing relevant parts of the output only):

```
Measure Start!
[0.132s][info][class,load] java.net.SocketAddress source: jrt:/java.base
[0.132s][info][class,load] java.net.InetSocketAddress source: jrt:/java.base
[0.132s][info][class,load] java.net.InetAddress source: shared objects file
[0.133s][info][class,load] jdk.internal.access.JavaNetInetAddressAccess source: shared objects file
[0.133s][info][class,load] java.net.InetAddress$1 source: shared objects file
[0.133s][info][class,load] java.net.InetAddress$InetAddressHolder source: shared objects file
[0.133s][info][class,load] java.util.SortedSet source: shared objects file
[0.133s][info][class,load] java.util.NavigableSet source: shared objects file
[0.133s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet source: shared objects file
[0.134s][info][class,load] java.util.SortedMap source: shared objects file
[0.134s][info][class,load] java.util.NavigableMap source: shared objects file
[0.134s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentNavigableMap source: shared objects file
[0.134s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap source: shared objects file
[0.134s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap$Index source: shared objects file
[0.134s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.atomic.Striped64 source: shared objects file
[0.134s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.atomic.LongAdder source: shared objects file
[0.134s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap$Node source: shared objects file
[0.134s][info][class,load] java.net.InetAddressImplFactory source: shared objects file
[0.134s][info][class,load] java.net.InetAddressImpl source: shared objects file
[0.134s][info][class,load] java.net.Inet6AddressImpl source: shared objects file
[0.134s][info][class,load] java.lang.Class$1 source: shared objects file
[0.135s][info][class,load] java.net.InetAddress$NameService source: shared objects file
[0.135s][info][class,load] java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService source: shared objects file
[0.135s][info][class,load] java.net.Inet4Address source: shared objects file
[0.135s][info][class,load] java.net.InetSocketAddress$InetSocketAddressHolder source: jrt:/java.base
[0.135s][info][class,load] java.net.SocketOptions source: jrt:/java.base
[0.135s][info][class,load] java.net.SocketImpl source: jrt:/java.base
[0.136s][info][class,load] java.net.SocketImpl$$Lambda$14/0x0000000800b69840 source: java.net.SocketImpl
[0.136s][info][class,load] sun.net.NetProperties source: jrt:/java.base
[0.136s][info][class,load] sun.net.NetProperties$1 source: jrt:/java.base
[0.136s][info][class,load] java.util.Properties$LineReader source: shared objects file
[0.137s][info][class,load] sun.net.PlatformSocketImpl source: jrt:/java.base
[0.138s][info][class,load] sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl source: jrt:/java.base
[0.138s][info][class,load] sun.nio.ch.NativeDispatcher source: jrt:/java.base
[0.138s][info][class,load] sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher source: jrt:/java.base
[0.138s][info][class,load] sun.nio.ch.IOUtil source: jrt:/java.base
[0.140s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer source: shared objects file
[0.140s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync source: shared objects file
[0.140s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync source: shared objects file
[0.140s][info][class,load] java.net.SocksConsts source: jrt:/java.base
[0.140s][info][class,load] java.net.DelegatingSocketImpl source: jrt:/java.base
[0.140s][info][class,load] java.net.SocksSocketImpl source: jrt:/java.base
[0.140s][info][class,load] sun.nio.ch.Net source: jrt:/java.base
[0.140s][info][class,load] java.net.ProtocolFamily source: jrt:/java.base
[0.140s][info][class,load] sun.nio.ch.Net$1 source: jrt:/java.base
[0.141s][info][class,load] sun.net.ext.ExtendedSocketOptions source: jrt:/java.base
[0.141s][info][class,load] jdk.net.ExtendedSocketOptions source: jrt:/jdk.net
[0.141s][info][class,load] java.net.SocketOption source: jrt:/java.base
[0.141s][info][class,load] jdk.net.ExtendedSocketOptions$ExtSocketOption source: jrt:/jdk.net
[0.141s][info][class,load] jdk.net.SocketFlow source: jrt:/jdk.net
[0.141s][info][class,load] jdk.net.ExtendedSocketOptions$PlatformSocketOptions source: jrt:/jdk.net
[0.141s][info][class,load] jdk.net.ExtendedSocketOptions$PlatformSocketOptions$1 source: jrt:/jdk.net
[0.141s][info][class,load] jdk.net.MacOSXSocketOptions source: jrt:/jdk.net
[0.143s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.ArraysKt__ArraysJVMKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.143s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.ArraysKt__ArraysKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.143s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysJvmKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.143s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.143s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.ArraysKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.143s][info][class,load] jdk.net.ExtendedSocketOptions$1 source: jrt:/jdk.net
[0.144s][info][class,load] java.net.Inet6Address source: shared objects file
[0.145s][info][class,load] java.net.Inet6Address$Inet6AddressHolder source: shared objects file
[0.151s][info][class,load] kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.151s][info][class,load] kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.152s][info][class,load] kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.152s][info][class,load] java.lang.AssertionError source: jrt:/java.base
[0.152s][info][class,load] java.lang.IllegalStateException source: jrt:/java.base
[0.152s][info][class,load] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException source: jrt:/java.base
[0.152s][info][class,load] java.net.StandardProtocolFamily source: jrt:/java.base
Measure End!
20704379 ns
```

Note the timestamps.

A *lot* of classes got loaded while you are doing `3 in arrayOf(4)`, because this is the first time you are using those classes. Note specifically that `kotlin.collections.ArraysKt` is loaded.

What if you do this first?

```
println("Calling setOf")
println(setOf(1, 2))
```

The output becomes:

```
Calling setOf
[0.126s][info][class,load] jdk.internal.access.JavaNetInetAddressAccess source: shared objects file
[0.126s][info][class,load] java.net.InetAddress$1 source: shared objects file
[0.126s][info][class,load] java.net.InetAddress$InetAddressHolder source: shared objects file
[0.126s][info][class,load] java.util.SortedSet source: shared objects file
[0.126s][info][class,load] java.util.NavigableSet source: shared objects file
[0.126s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet source: shared objects file
[0.126s][info][class,load] java.util.SortedMap source: shared objects file
[0.126s][info][class,load] java.util.NavigableMap source: shared objects file
[0.126s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentNavigableMap source: shared objects file
[0.126s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap source: shared objects file
[0.126s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap$Index source: shared objects file
[0.126s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.atomic.Striped64 source: shared objects file
[0.126s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.atomic.LongAdder source: shared objects file
[0.126s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap$Node source: shared objects file
[0.126s][info][class,load] java.net.InetAddressImplFactory source: shared objects file
[0.127s][info][class,load] java.net.InetAddressImpl source: shared objects file
[0.127s][info][class,load] java.net.Inet6AddressImpl source: shared objects file
[0.127s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.SetsKt__SetsJVMKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.127s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.SetsKt__SetsKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.127s][info][class,load] java.lang.Class$1 source: shared objects file
[0.127s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.SetsKt___SetsKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.127s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.SetsKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.127s][info][class,load] java.net.InetAddress$NameService source: shared objects file
[0.127s][info][class,load] java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService source: shared objects file
[0.127s][info][class,load] java.net.Inet4Address source: shared objects file
[0.127s][info][class,load] java.net.InetSocketAddress$InetSocketAddressHolder source: jrt:/java.base
[0.128s][info][class,load] java.net.SocketOptions source: jrt:/java.base
[0.128s][info][class,load] java.net.SocketImpl source: jrt:/java.base
[0.128s][info][class,load] kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.128s][info][class,load] java.net.SocketImpl$$Lambda$14/0x0000000800b6a040 source: java.net.SocketImpl
[0.128s][info][class,load] kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.129s][info][class,load] sun.net.NetProperties source: jrt:/java.base
[0.129s][info][class,load] sun.net.NetProperties$1 source: jrt:/java.base
[0.129s][info][class,load] java.util.Properties$LineReader source: shared objects file
[0.129s][info][class,load] kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.129s][info][class,load] java.lang.AssertionError source: jrt:/java.base
[0.129s][info][class,load] java.lang.IllegalStateException source: jrt:/java.base
[0.129s][info][class,load] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException source: jrt:/java.base
[0.130s][info][class,load] sun.net.PlatformSocketImpl source: jrt:/java.base
[0.130s][info][class,load] sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl source: jrt:/java.base
[0.130s][info][class,load] sun.nio.ch.NativeDispatcher source: jrt:/java.base
[0.130s][info][class,load] sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher source: jrt:/java.base
[0.130s][info][class,load] sun.nio.ch.IOUtil source: jrt:/java.base
[0.132s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer source: shared objects file
[0.132s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync source: shared objects file
[0.132s][info][class,load] java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync source: shared objects file
[0.132s][info][class,load] java.net.SocksConsts source: jrt:/java.base
[0.132s][info][class,load] java.net.DelegatingSocketImpl source: jrt:/java.base
[0.132s][info][class,load] java.net.SocksSocketImpl source: jrt:/java.base
[0.133s][info][class,load] sun.nio.ch.Net source: jrt:/java.base
[0.133s][info][class,load] java.net.ProtocolFamily source: jrt:/java.base
[0.133s][info][class,load] sun.nio.ch.Net$1 source: jrt:/java.base
[0.133s][info][class,load] sun.net.ext.ExtendedSocketOptions source: jrt:/java.base
[0.133s][info][class,load] jdk.net.ExtendedSocketOptions source: jrt:/jdk.net
[0.133s][info][class,load] java.net.SocketOption source: jrt:/java.base
[0.133s][info][class,load] jdk.net.ExtendedSocketOptions$ExtSocketOption source: jrt:/jdk.net
[0.133s][info][class,load] jdk.net.SocketFlow source: jrt:/jdk.net
[0.133s][info][class,load] jdk.net.ExtendedSocketOptions$PlatformSocketOptions source: jrt:/jdk.net
[0.133s][info][class,load] jdk.net.ExtendedSocketOptions$PlatformSocketOptions$1 source: jrt:/jdk.net
[0.133s][info][class,load] jdk.net.MacOSXSocketOptions source: jrt:/jdk.net
[0.135s][info][class,load] jdk.net.ExtendedSocketOptions$1 source: jrt:/jdk.net
[0.136s][info][class,load] java.net.Inet6Address source: shared objects file
[0.136s][info][class,load] java.net.Inet6Address$Inet6AddressHolder source: shared objects file
[0.139s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.ArraysKt__ArraysJVMKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.139s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.ArraysKt__ArraysKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.139s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysJvmKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.139s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.139s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.ArraysKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.143s][info][class,load] java.net.StandardProtocolFamily source: jrt:/java.base
[0.146s][info][class,load] sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$$Lambda$15/0x0000000800b6a440 source: sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl
[0.146s][info][class,load] java.net.SocksSocketImpl$3 source: jrt:/java.base
[0.146s][info][class,load] java.net.ProxySelector source: jrt:/java.base
[0.146s][info][class,load] sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector source: jrt:/java.base
[0.146s][info][class,load] java.net.Proxy source: jrt:/java.base
[0.147s][info][class,load] java.net.Proxy$Type source: jrt:/java.base
[0.147s][info][class,load] sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector$1 source: jrt:/java.base
[0.147s][info][class,load] sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector$NonProxyInfo source: jrt:/java.base
[0.147s][info][class,load] sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector$3 source: jrt:/java.base
[0.147s][info][class,load] sun.net.NetHooks source: jrt:/java.base
[0.147s][info][class,load] sun.net.NetHooks$Provider source: jrt:/java.base
[0.147s][info][class,load] sun.net.sdp.SdpProvider source: jrt:/java.base
[0.148s][info][class,load] sun.nio.ch.NativeThread source: jrt:/java.base
[0.150s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.MapsKt__MapWithDefaultKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.150s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.MapsKt__MapsJVMKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.150s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.MapsKt__MapsKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.150s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.MapsKt___MapsKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.150s][info][class,load] kotlin.collections.MapsKt source: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar
[0.150s][info][class,load] java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeySet source: jrt:/java.base
[0.151s][info][class,load] java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator source: shared objects file
[0.151s][info][class,load] java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator source: jrt:/java.base
[1, 2]
Measure Start!
Measure End!
19515 ns
```

As you can see, now all that class loading is done before you start measuring. Specifically, `kotlin.collections.ArraysKt` also got loaded here (at 0.139s).

If you call `arrayOf` rather than `setOf` first, however, it won't work as effectively, because `arrayOf` is `inline`. The Kotlin compiler directly translates `arrayOf(1, 2)` to `new Integer[] { 1, 2 }`, which doesn't use anything in `ArraysKt`, so it doesn't cause `ArraysKt` to be loaded.

If you call `setOf` with one element, a similar thing happens. The single parameter `setOf` calls `java.util.Collections.singleton`, so it doesn't use anything in `ArraysKt` either :(

You can also experiment with the JVM option `-XX:+PrintCompilation`. It shows you when each method is being JIT compiled. The time required to JIT compile methods could also be a reason why calling `in` the first time is slow.

See also: [Why does the JVM require warmup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198278/why-does-the-jvm-require-warmup)

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful! To solve my original problem on Android, I was able to pass `adb shell setprop dalvik.vm.extra-opts -verbose:class` and observe the same class loading on ART as well.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `measureTimeMillis` uses the `System.currentTimeMillis()` system function, which is usually no precise enough for use cases as yours. You need a more precise measurement to measure such short-lived processes. For this, use `measureNanoTime`.

As other users have noted, the Just in time compiler of the JVM usually takes a bit of time to make Classes available at runtime. If you run your code twice, and only measure the second run, you should get much better results.

```
import kotlin.system.measureNanoTime

fun main() {
  val init: Boolean = 3 in arrayOf(4)
  val timeInNanos = measureNanoTime {
    3 in arrayOf(4)
  }
  println("$timeInNanos ns")
}
```

On Kotlin-play: https://play.kotlinlang.org/?_gl=1*sbvwfn*_ga*MTMwNjUxNzc1My4xNjIwMTEyMDY5*_ga_J6T75801PF*MTYyOTEwMDQzMy4yOC4xLjE2MjkxMDExMTUuMA..&_ga=2.877105.1220867763.1629100434-1306517753.1620112069#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS41LjIxIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiaW1wb3J0IGtvdGxpbi5zeXN0ZW0ubWVhc3VyZU5hbm9UaW1lXG5cbmZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuICB2YWwgaW5pdDogQm9vbGVhbiA9IDMgaW4gYXJyYXlPZig0KVxuICB2YWwgdGltZUluTmFub3MgPSBtZWFzdXJlTmFub1RpbWUge1xuICAgIDMgaW4gYXJyYXlPZig0KVxuICB9XG4gIHByaW50bG4oXCIkdGltZUluTmFub3MgbnNcIilcbn0ifQ==

[image: Result of code]

3503 ns are about 1/300000 th of a second.

For a more reliable benchmark, measure the total tile multiple runs take, and divide by the number. An average will probably be more telling anyway.

Comment: I can reproduce a similar result with `measureNanoTime` though. It becomes very fast (though not 0ns) if you call `setOf` first.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, I guess the JIT compiler does need a bit to make everything available via ClassLoader and such. Running the thing twice, and measuring only the second run will probably yield a more representative result.