# How to time Spark program execution speed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, lazy-evaluation, distributed-computing

I want to time my Spark program execution speed but due to laziness it's quite difficult. Let's take into account this (meaningless) code here:

```
var graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(context, args(0))
val graph_degs = graph.outerJoinVertices(graph.degrees).triplets.cache

/* I'd need to start the timer here */
val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis  
val edges = graph_degs.flatMap(trip =>  { /* do something*/ })
                      .union(graph_degs)

val count = edges.count
val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis 
/* I'd need to stop the timer here */

println("It took " + t2-t1 + " to count " + count)
```

The thing is, transformations are lazily so nothing gets evaluated before `val count = edges.count` line. But according to my point of view `t1` gets a value despite the code above hasn't a value... the code above `t1` gets evaluated after the timer started despite the position in the code. That's a problem...

In Spark Web UI I can't find anything interesting about it since I need the time spent after that specific line of code. Do you think is there a easy solution to see when a group of transformation gets evaluated for real?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to profile methods in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160001/how-to-profile-methods-in-scala)

Comment: Doesn't seem like a duplicate as this post is specific to Apache Spark, which provides specific measurement tools and presents specific profiling challenges - like the one described here: evaluation is lazy and therefore evaluated block of code might not represent the measured operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since consecutive transformations (within the same *task* - meaning, they are not separated by *shuffles* and performed as part of the same *action*) are performed as a single "step", Spark does **not** measure them individually. And from Driver code - you can't either.

What you *can* do is measure the duration of applying *your* function to each record, and use an *Accumulator* to sum it all up, e.g.:

```
// create accumulator
val durationAccumulator = sc.longAccumulator("flatMapDuration")

// "wrap" your "doSomething" operation with time measurement, and add to accumulator
val edges = rdd.flatMap(trip => {
  val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis
  val result = doSomething(trip)
  val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis
  durationAccumulator.add(t2 - t1)
  result
})

// perform the action that would trigger evaluation
val count = edges.count

// now you can read the accumulated value
println("It took " + durationAccumulator.value + " to flatMap " + count)
```

You can repeat this for any individual transformation.

**Disclaimers**:

- Of course, this will not include the time Spark spent shuffling things around and doing the actual counting - for that, indeed, the Spark UI is your best resource.
- Note that accumulators are sensitive to things like retries - a retried task will update the accumulator twice.

**Style Note**:
You can make this code more reusable by creating a `measure` function that "wraps" around any function and updates a given accumulator:

```
// write this once:
def measure[T, R](action: T => R, acc: LongAccumulator): T => R = input => { 
  val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis
  val result = action(input)
  val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis
  acc.add(t2 - t1)
  result
}

// use it with any transformation:
rdd.flatMap(measure(doSomething, durationAccumulator))
```

Comment: Yea that's a good idea! But not so accurate because as you said "this will not include the time Spark spent shuffling things around and doing the actual counting". Interesting anyway.

Comment: I have the same problem but I want to measure a "joinWithCassandraTable" transformation, so I can't use accumulators inside of this method, any other alternative?

Comment: What is the difference between this approach and `spark.time(myFunction)`?

Comment: `spark.time(myFunction)` runs entirely on the driver, it can't be used for functions that transform the actual distributed data on the worker nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The Spark Web UI records every single action, and even reports times of every stage of that action - it's all in there! You need to looks through the stages tab, not the jobs. I've found it's only useable though if you compile and submit your code. It is useless in the REPL, are you using this by any chance?