# Why does my Map claim to have no keys after adding keys?

Tags: scala

I have a map of Int->Queue, and I'm adding to the queues one entry at a time. At the end of the process I need to iterate over the keys and values (because I want to convert the Queues to Arrays), but scala says there are no keys/values in the map. Some simplified code below for illustration purposes. What is going on here? The result of m(4) below is also puzzling.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue

val m = Map[Int, Queue[Int]]().withDefaultValue(Queue[Int]())

m(1) += 10
res25: scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(10)

m(1) += 10
res26: scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(10, 10)

m(1)
res35: scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(10, 10)

m(4)
res37: scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(10, 10)

m.keys
res28: Iterable[Int] = Set()

m
res36: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Int]] = Map()
```

Using scala 2.10.3.

Answer (score 2):

You never add anything to the map.  You are getting the mutable queue that you set as the default value and modifying that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do have to check if the `Queue` at a given index has been created or not, but the syntax need not be quite so "laborious."

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue
val mutablemap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, Queue[Int]]()

mutablemap(9) = mutablemap.lift(9).fold(Queue(99))(_ += 99)
mutablemap(2) = mutablemap.lift(2).fold(Queue(22))(_ += 22)
mutablemap(9) = mutablemap.lift(9).fold(Queue(19))(_ += 19)
mutablemap(2) = mutablemap.lift(2).fold(Queue(12))(_ += 12)

mutablemap(9)  // res0: scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(99, 19)
mutablemap(2)  // res1: scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(22, 12)
```

**update**

On further reflection, your original design wasn't too far off the mark.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue
val mutablemap = 
  scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, Queue[Int]]().withDefault(_ => Queue[Int]())

mutablemap(3) = mutablemap(3) += 37
mutablemap(3) = mutablemap(3) += 45
mutablemap(6) = mutablemap(6) += 60
mutablemap(6) = mutablemap(6) += 62

mutablemap(3)  // res0: scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(37, 45)
mutablemap(6)  // res1: scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(60, 62)
```

Comment: When you do mutablemap(6) = mutablemap(6) += 62 , is that O(1) or O(N) where N is the length of the queue?

Comment: According to the [ScalaDocs page](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Queue.html), the `+=` method "appends a single element to this buffer. This takes constant time."

Comment: I was wondering about the `=` in `mutablemap(6) =`. Is this deleting the existing N length queue and replacing it with a new one, or is it O(1) due to smart internal handling of references?

Comment: I'd be a bit surprised if the entire operation were O(N), but I don't really know.

Comment: @foghorn Appending to Queue is O(1) as said.  Accessing a HashMap element is  effectively O(1), but this performance can degrade if you have a poor hashing algorithm.  Also keep in mind the cost to calculate the hashcode of your key as well.  Your keys are Ints so it's not a concern here.  So you can say this operation as a whole should be O(1).

Comment: Yes, the `+=` is definitely O(1). I'm not sure about the `=`. It's probably O(1), but might be O(N). Maybe I'll try to time it later.

Comment: Confirmed it is also O(1) using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160001/how-to-profile-methods-in-scala

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging puhlen's answer:

First, I need to switch to a mutable map. Second, the use of withDefaultValue seems to be irrelevant to this problem (which is counterintuitive).

```
val mutablemap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, Queue[Int]]()
```

When adding key-value pairs to the map, I have to laboriously check to see if the key exists first (because I don't want to destroy any pre-existing key-value pair, because I'm incrementally building up the queues):

```
if (mutablemap.contains(key)) {
    // mutate the existing Queue
    mutablemap(key) += new_value
} else {
    // key was not in map; start a new Queue
    mutablemap += key -> Queue[Int](first_value)
}
```