# scala - why map.size return 0 when the map is not empty

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am new to scala. Following example I am a bit confused what is going on. I created a mutable map, then pushed three key/value to the map. I can retrieve the queue with values by key, but "web.keys" it shows the map is empty, and "web.size" returns 0! why is this, and how can I retrieve the correct map size?

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.{Map, Set, Queue, ArrayBuffer}

scala> val web = Map[Int, Queue[Long]]().withDefaultValue(Queue()) 
web: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Long]] = Map()

scala> web(123).enqueue(567L)

scala> web(123).enqueue(1L)

scala> web(123).enqueue(2L)

scala> web(123)
res96: scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Long] = Queue(567, 1, 2)

scala> web
res97: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Long]] = Map()

scala> web.size
res98: Int = 0

scala> web.keys
res99: Iterable[Int] = Set()
```

A simple map works fine.

```
scala> val w= Map[Int,Int]()
w: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map()

scala> w(1)=1

scala> w
res10: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1)

scala> w(2)=2

scala> w
res12: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(2 -> 2, 1 -> 1)

scala> w.size
res13: Int = 2
```

I tried more experiment, seems it has something to do with "withDefaultValue". But how do I fix it?

```
scala> val ww= Map[Int,Int]().withDefaultValue(0) 
ww: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map()

scala> ww
res14: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map()

scala> ww(1) += 1

scala> ww(2) += 2

scala>  w.size
res17: Int = 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my Map claim to have no keys after adding keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532916/why-does-my-map-claim-to-have-no-keys-after-adding-keys) or [Behaviour of withDefaultValue in mutable.Map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46650121/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When default value is returned from map it is not added to map! So when invoking `web(123)`

nothing is added to map, only default value is returned. Use `getOrElseUpdate` method to read data **instead** of using map with default value. Or simply take into consideration that default value is not in map as other key - value pairs.

I think you are misunderstanding your examples:

In first example `web(123).enqueue(567L)` you are retrieveing default value and adding 567L to default value (Queue). Nothing is added to map.

In second example `w(1)=1` you are adding data to map

In third example `ww(1) += 1` you are retrieving default value (0) and adding 1 to it.

In general using `map(K)` will return value for key K, while `map(K) = V` will set value V for key K.

Under the hood invoking `map(K)` and `map(K) = V` uses apply and update methods. See http://otfried.org/scala/apply.html or other scala documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks! I see. I thought it would work like python defaultdict.

Comment: just to stress (this is what confused me when I saw this). if you would do web(124) you would still get the enqueued default value. The default value is a mutable queue you are changing.