# How measure time for scala functions without invocation?

Tags: scala

Cosider example for scala time funciton measuring:

```
def time[R](block: => R): R = {
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    val result = block    // call-by-name
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time: " + (t1 - t0) + "ns")
    result
}
```

Source taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9160068/1251549).

Now try this code:

```
object MapTimeMeasure {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val intToString: Int => String = x => s"$x"
    val intToString2: Int => String = time (intToString)
  }
}
```

And you will see `Elapsed time` in the logs. So this time function can be used only for measuring time invocation "right now". But how to measure time for function without invocation? E.g. `time` just wraps function and executes it only when wrapped funciton is called **not** when `time` invocated itself. How to do this in scala?

Comment: I neither understand what you want, nor do I understand what your code is doing. The `intToString` value is just a constant function literal, it doesn't do anything at all. Passing it to `time` doesn't make any sense, because you are measuring only the time that `time` itself is taking, and nothing else.

Comment: 1) `intToString` is just for example, (look at realted question) there can be any different function to pass in time. 2) the problem is `time` invocation leads to "time measuring" while it is needed to just chain funciton calls.

Comment: Just pass the function in as a T=>R. You have tried to make it the same as call-by-name, but there is a slight but subtle difference between these forms. Your invocation will have to be adjusted too--as now you aren't passing in an Int at all so, as @AndreyTyukin says, you aren't actually *doing* anything.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `time` is called only once when you define function `intToString2` but you probably want to call `time` every time function is called

```
val intToString: Int => String = x => s"$x"
val intToString2: Int => String = i => time (intToString(i))
```

and you can write decorator function that measures time

```
def timeF[A,B](func: A=>B): A=>B = {
  a => time(func(a))
}

val intToString: Int => String = x => s"$x"
val intToString2: Int => String = timeF(intToString)
```