# Is synchronous HTTP request wrapped in a Future considered CPU or IO bound?

Tags: scala, concurrency, future, scalaj-http, sttp

Consider the following two snippets where first wraps scalaj-http requests with `Future`, whilst second uses async-http-client

[Sync](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/65FeYKoQTqCiZJufu2LrWg) client wrapped with Future using global EC

```
object SyncClientWithFuture {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    import scalaj.http.Http
    val delay = "3000"
    val slowApi = s"http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/delay/${delay}/url/https://www.google.co.uk"
    val nestedF = Future(Http(slowApi).asString).flatMap { _ =>
      Future.sequence(List(
        Future(Http(slowApi).asString),
        Future(Http(slowApi).asString),
        Future(Http(slowApi).asString)
      ))
    }
    time { Await.result(nestedF, Inf) }
  }
}
```

[Async](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/tRPjAzCRTh2dTLLEkCjdTw) client using global EC

```
object AsyncClient {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    import sttp.client._
    import sttp.client.asynchttpclient.future.AsyncHttpClientFutureBackend
    implicit val sttpBackend = AsyncHttpClientFutureBackend()
    val delay = "3000"
    val slowApi = uri"http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/delay/${delay}/url/https://www.google.co.uk"
    val nestedF = basicRequest.get(slowApi).send().flatMap { _ =>
      Future.sequence(List(
        basicRequest.get(slowApi).send(),
        basicRequest.get(slowApi).send(),
        basicRequest.get(slowApi).send()
      ))
    }
    time { Await.result(nestedF, Inf) }
  }
}
```

The snippets are using

- [Slowwly](http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/#go) to simulate slow API
- [scalaj-http](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http)
- [async-http-client](https://sttp.softwaremill.com/en/latest/backends/future.html#using-async-http-client) sttp backend
- [time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9160068/5205022)

The former takes 12 seconds whilst the latter takes 6 seconds. It seems the former behaves as if it is CPU bound however I do not see how that is the case since `Future#sequence` should executes the HTTP requests in parallel? Why does synchronous client wrapped in `Future` behave differently from proper async client? Is it not the case that async client does the same kind of thing where it wraps calls in Futures under the hood?

Comment: AFAIK, it should be considered **IO** bounded, since the thread won't be doing anything but waiting. A proper async client would not block a real compute thread, so the ec should be free of making more calls, whereas the sycn client will block the threads. - BTW, you may wan to use `traverse` so the petitions are not started when the list is defined and you may want to add a thirds snippet using the sync client but wrapped on a `scala concurrent.blocking` block.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Is it not the case that behaviour is determined by the kind of execution context being used, and since we are using the same `global` EC for both clients, should the behaviour not be the same?

Comment: Why? Is like saying that two similar functions but with different complexities should execute the same if we run both using the **JVM**. - BTW, what is the nature of `global` in your environment? Are you running in an environment with only one thread?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I am running these two examples just in scastie (there are links in the OP). So the async client effectively does something like `Future(blocking(task))` instead of just `Future(task)`, and it is this characteristic of it that makes it truly async?

Comment: Ah then yes, I believe **Scastie** uses a single thread for its `global`. - A truly async client should do something better than `blocking`, because `blocking` _(when works, for example for a single-threaded ec it does nothing)_ will just create a new thread to be blocked. Whereas a truly async client should not block anything but rather work using callbacks. Take a look to the event loop in **JS**, you can not block it and you can nor create a new one to block, everything has to be truly asynchronous.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez `println(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global)` gives `parallelism = 6` in scastie.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218662/discussion-between-mario-galic-and-luis-miguel-mejia-suarez).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Future#sequence should execute the HTTP requests in parallel?

First of all, `Future#sequence` doesn't execute anything. It just produces a future that completes when all parameters complete.
Evaluation (execution) of constructed futures starts immediately If there is a free thread in the EC. Otherwise, it simply submits it for a sort of queue.
I am sure that in the first case you have single thread execution of futures.

> println(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global) -> parallelism = 6

Don't know why it is like this, it might that other 5 thread is always busy for some reason. You can experiment with explicitly created new EC with 5-10 threads.

The difference with the Async case that you don't create a future by yourself, it is provided by the library, that internally don't block the thread. It starts the async process, "subscribes" for a result, and returns the future, which completes when the result will come.

Actually, async lib could have another EC internally, but I doubt.

Btw, Futures are not supposed to contain slow/io/blocking evaluations without `blocking`. Otherwise, you potentially will block the main thread pool (EC) and your app will be completely frozen.