# java - system.nanoTime() runs too slow

Tags: java, nanotime

I am using system.nanoTime in my app and I calculate time relative to a starttime.
My app ran very well until I copied it to a new computer and on it the nano time gives me slower values.

I wrote a simple app just to make sure.
the nano time is compared to the system time.
It shows the same values in other computers except my new one . any suggestions?

Here is my code:
First I have

```
private long initNanoTime = System.nanoTime();
private long initTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

than I loop a thread that runs every second:

```
long timeUsingNanoTime = initTime + (System.nanoTime() - initNanoTime) / 1000000;
long timeUsingMilis = System.currentTimeMillis();
long nanotimeOffset = Math.abs(timeUsingNanoTime - timeUsingMilis);
if (nanotimeOffset < 100l) ? print("close") : print(far);
```

Edit : I am using nano because I need to handle even ts that occur in nano time and print to a log the nano time which it was received in

Comment: What do you mean with "gives me slower values". Does the method execution takes more time or do you get a value you dont expect? Maybe this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's like the Java API docs say about [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29):

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not
>   related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value
>   returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary origin
>   time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). The same
>   origin is used by all invocations of this method in an instance of a
>   Java virtual machine; other virtual machine instances are likely to
>   use a different origin.
>
> This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily
>   nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no
>   guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as
>   that of currentTimeMillis().

It does not provide any coupling with the timestamp (currentTimeMillis) and does not provide a fixed resolution.

In your case it seems that Java now has a higher resolution timer available than before, and so does not need to use the system time.

Comment: Is that more reliable than the 6 and 5 version of nanotime http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29

Comment: They're both saying basically the same. Both state that `nanoTime` is not coupled to any specific origin, so you can't rely on that. They just added some more explanations in the Java7 docs.