# Why does my UART performance in Java vary?

Tags: java, performance, stream, serial-port, uart

I'm using an ordinary serial port on a PC to send and receive data in a Java application. The PC runs Windows XP SP3 with java 1.6.0. Here is the code:

```
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;

// Open the serial port.
CommPortIdentifier portId;
SerialPort serialPort;
portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM1");
serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("My serial port", 1000 /* 1 second timeout */);
serialPort.setSerialPortParams(115200, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

// Set up input and output streams which will be used to receive and transmit data on the UART.
InputStream input;
OutputStream output;
input = serialPort.getInputStream();
output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

// Wrap the input and output streams in buffers to improve performance. 1024 is the buffer size in bytes. 
input = new BufferedInputStream(input, 1024);
output = new BufferedOutputStream(output, 1024);

// Sync connection.
// Validate connection.
// Start Send- and Receive threads (see below).
// Send a big chunk of data.
```

To send data I've set up a thread that takes packages from a queue (ArrayBlockingQueue) and sends it on the UART. Similar for receive. Other parts of the application can simply insert packages into the send queue and then poll the receive queue to get the reply.

```
private class SendThread extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    try {
      SendPkt pkt = SendQueue.take();
      // Register Time1.
      output.write(pkt.data);
      output.flush();
      // Register Time2.
      // Put the data length and Time2-Time1 into an array.

      // Receive Acknowledge.
      ResponsePkt RspPkt = new ResponsePkt();
      RspPkt.data = receive(); // This function calls "input.read" and checks for errors.
      ReceiveQueue.put(RspPkt);
    } catch (IOException e) { ... }
  }
```

Each send packet is at most 256 bytes, which should take 256*8 bits / 115200 bits/s = 17,7ms to transfer.

I put measurements of Time2-Time1 in an array, i.e. the send time, and check it later. It turns out that sometimes a transfer of 256 bytes takes 15ms to transfer, which seems good since it's close to the teoretical minimum. I'm not sure though why it's faster in practice than in theory. However, the problem is that sometimes a transfer of 256 bytes takes 32ms, i.e. twice as much as needed. What could be causing this?

/Henrik

Comment: I saw you added "input = new BufferedInputStream(input, 1024);" I thought that would of fixed my problem but this does not seem to do anything. Looks like you are going to be limited to the size of the buffer on the actual UART chip, nothing more nothing less. Tried differrent sizes then sent myself chars and it kept maximizing at 4096. I wish there was a way to know the maximum buffer size of a uart though java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you measure the time with System.nanoTime()?

Windows clock resolution used by System.currentTimeMillis() is by default around 15ms so perhaps in real time each task takes 20ms but some are spread over two ticks instead of one.

See [System.currentTimeMillis vs System.nanoTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

A (windows) PC is not a real-time machine. That means that when ever your application has to access a hardware layer it may be delayed. You have no control over this and there is no fixed amount of time between entering your function and exiting your function due to how the system (kernel) works.

Most Linux machines behave the same way. There are other tasks (applications) running in the background which consume processing power and thus your application might be moved around a bit in the process queue before sending the real data.

Even in the sending process there might be delays between each byte being send. This is all handled by the kernel/hardware layer and your software can't change that.

If you do need real-time excecution then you'll have to look for a [real-time operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system).

This line sums it up pretty nicely:

> A key characteristic of an RTOS is the level of its consistency concerning the amount of time it takes to accept and complete an application's task; the variability is jitter.

Where with a RTOS this jitter is known/defined and with a normal OS this jitter is unknown/undefined.

Comment: OK thanks. Could it help if I ran my java application in Windows with a higher priority? Like this in the Windows command prompt:

start /HIGH javaw -jar MyApp.jar

Comment: Hardly. It might make some difference, but not noticable I guess (never tried it, never had a need for it).

Comment: Also, you are using Java. I am not a real java expect but afaik Java runs on one thread along with the scheduler and garbage collector (correct me if I am wrong). These also take up processing time. And if your method is interrupted by the garbage collector then you'll still have a delay in the execution.

Comment: I just tried "start /HIGH" and "start /REALTIME" but saw no differences.

The other threads you mention in java sound interesting. Is there a way to tell the other threads that "I need to finish a block of code without interruption"?

One more thing: My time measurements usually look like this:
15, 32, 15, 31, 16, 31, 16, 31, 16, 31, 16, 31, 16, 31, 15, 32

So in general, every second time takes longer then it should. Does that give any hint?

Comment: I tried "setPriority(MAX_PRIORITY);" in my send thread. No improvement.

Comment: Do you measure the time with System.nanoTime()? IIRC Windows clock resolution used by System.currentTimesMilles() is by default around 15ms so perhaps in real time each task takes 20ms but some are spread over two tick instead of one. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime for example

Comment: Thanks @WalterLaan, that helped a lot! Now my times are much more stable, around 22ms for each 256-byte transfer. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it.