# Speed up or slow down time - A clock whose time is different from system clock?

Tags: java, time, clock

My aim is to speed up or slow down time.

**Note:** All units of time in double quotes ("some time") are NOT real units of time. They are notional units of time.

I want to make a clock which is runs exactly like a regular clock, except that 250 milliseconds = 1 "second", 60 "seconds" or rather 250 * 60 milliseconds = 1 "minute" etc. I also want to be able to change this clock to use any another value of milliseconds as 1 second eg 1000 (normal,real world time) , 6000 ms (ie 6 sec = 1 "sec") etc.

Is there any reliable API or code to do this ? If not, then how do I do it ?

I saw a question on SO, but did not get any code, API or suggestions on how to implement such a clock or what could be the potential problems in such a clock - [Java - Creating an Internal Clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791954/java-creating-an-internal-clock)

That post talks about [callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29), but I don't know if its the best and problem free way to make my clock.

Comment: This question does not seem to be bad. I am confident that most people would find it worth looking at, if not very interesting or a good question. Why the -1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously create a class `MyClock.java`. On instantiation save the current System Time. Implement a method `long getTime()` that takes the diference from now and the saved time on instatiation. Then apply delatation on the given miliiseconds (multiply by 4) ... rest is yours.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to just base your time off of the system clock, for example:

```
class CustomClock()
{
    private final long offset;

    public CustomClock(){
        offset = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public long getSeconds()
    {
        return ((System.currentTimeMillis() - offset) / 250);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Then your code would look like

```
CustomClock clock = new CustomClock();
clock.getSeconds();    // Returns the number of "seconds" since you created 
                       //  the CustomClock object.
```