# Java: Time Resolution

Tags: java, time

Is there any inbuilt class in java se / java ee representig an arbitrary "Time Resolution"; e.g every hour, every second, all 10 minutes etc. ?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Schedule a task for periodic execution?

Comment: @JoaoSilva No, actually I have to pass such a time resolution into a service so it can perform business logic on a set of data

Comment: This post may be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at [java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum, you may use the units from here.

*Don't reinvent the wheel.*

For more complex time operation I would suggest [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library.

Comment: Integer division is much more simple

Comment: +1 for Joda - the problem with TimeUnit is that, as the name says, it only specifies the unit - the number of units must be specified separately. Joda's Period and Duration classes sound close to what @Paranaix is looking for.

Comment: @user3001: integer division may be simpler, but TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5) sure reads better and makes intent more clear.

Comment: @PeterŠtibraný Its not obvious to me what 5 is in `toMillis(5)` Is it millis or nano-seconds or hour, it could return 0 for all I know ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: it is (5) minutes to milliseconds, exactly as you read it :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can always reduce the resolution of a time e.g.

```
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
long seconds = millis / 1000;
long minutes = seconds / 60;
long hours = minutes / 60;
```

so if you want half hourly you can use

```
long halfHour = System.currentTimeMillis() / (30 * 60 * 1000L)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Granularity Units

If you meant simply a way to indicate a certain granularity of time such as hour versus minute versus second, the [accepted Answer by Kremser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438608/642706) is correct. The `TimeUnit` enum is exactly this. But you have another choice also built into Java.

### `ChronoUnit`

Note that Java 8 and later has a similar but longer list of values in [`java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) versus the seven in `TimeUnit`:

- FOREVER
- ERAS
- MILLENNIA
- CENTURIES
- DECADES
- YEARS
- MONTHS
- WEEKS
- DAYS
- HALF_DAYS
- HOURS
- MINUTES
- SECONDS
- MILLIS
- MICROS
- NANOS

Both enums, `TimeUnit` & `ChronoUnit`, are handy. Conversion between units is offered by `TimeUnit` in various methods. `ChronoUnit` calculates elapsed time with its [`between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) method.

## Clock increments

If you want the clock to tick in certain increments, the [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) class offers alternate implementations.

- [`Clock.tickSeconds`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#tickSeconds-java.time.ZoneId-) – Current time increments in whole seconds.
- [`Clock.tickMinutes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#tickMinutes-java.time.ZoneId-) – Current time increments in whole minutes.
- [`Clock.tick`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#tick-java.time.Clock-java.time.Duration-) – Current time increments in an amount you specify

Pass your alternate `Clock` implementation object as an optional argument in many java.time classes for use instead of the default clock.

## Truncate values

If you have a date-time value and want to truncate it to drop smaller fields to zero, look at the [`truncatedTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-). You specify the granularity with the [`TemporalUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html) interface, with implementations found in [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html).

For example, get the current moment, drop the fraction-of-second and seconds to get a value with whole minutes.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
ZonedDateTime nowWholeMinutes = now.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MINUTES );
```

Answer (score -1):

Use integer division, its simple:

`long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();`

will give you the current time in milliseconds.
If you want a time where the value would change only each `resolution` milliseconds (e.g.  each 1000 milliseconds), you can use integer division:

```
long resolution = 1000;
long result = millis / resolution * resolution
```

If you divide millis by resulution, you will get seconds in this example. `/` does integer division, because both `millis` and `resolution` are integral variables. That would be the same as `Math.floor(((float)millis) / ((float) resolution)))`. If you now multiply by `resolution`, the result will only change if a new resolution unit is reached.

Example: Lets assume you want a clock of which the time only changes if a new 5 Minutes block is reached, so a block is e.g 0-4 minutes, 5-9 minutes, 10-15 minutes, etc.
5 Minutes are 1000 milliseconds / second * 60 seconds/ minute * 5 minutes = 300000 milliseconds.
So, if you set `resolution = 300000`, `result` will only change for each 5 Minute block once.
For millis = 0-299999, result=0. For millis=300000-599999, result=5, etc. You get the idea I guess.