# Regarding calculating the total time taken to read the file

Tags: java, time, io

I have an log file named abcd.log in my C: drive that I am reading it through a java program , I want to measure How much time the program had taken to completely read the log file please advise how to achieve this..!!

```
public class Readdemo {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("C://abcd.log");
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : "
                    + fis.available());

            int content;
            while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
                // convert to char and display it
                System.out.print((char) content);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null)
                    fis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have come up with this..

```
public class BufferedRedeem {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C://abcd.log"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }
            long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

            System.out.println("Total execution time taken in millis: "
                    + elapsedTime);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @ratchetfreak - you're assuming this is a small file, aren't you ?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to record the before/after time in milliseconds.

`System.nanoTime()` is another option but it's worth reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime) to understand differences and usages.