# Execution time of a sql query using jstl

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, jstl

I am using jstl to access a database table. After a query has been executed, I need to find its execution time using jstl. I have attached the code I use:

```
<sql:update dataSource="${conn}" var="addresses">
    ${query}
</sql:update>
```

Is there a way to find it? I use ${addresses} to find the number of rows affected.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What execution time are you looking for? From your app-server or from database? With timezone, without?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

```
<jsp:useBean id="beginUpdate" class="java.util.Date"/>
<sql:update dataSource="${conn}" var="addresses">
    ${query}
</sql:update>
<jsp:useBean id="endUpdate" class="java.util.Date"/>
<c:set var="updateDuration" value="${endUpdate.time - beginUpdate.time}"/>
```

But this really isn't the best way to accurately time the update. However, if all you need is a general measure of how long it takes, then it's probably fine.

Comment: I don't know if its possible but it will be better to get the time values from `System.nanoTime` as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime)