# Duplicate millisecond timestamp issue

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, duplicates

I am trying to rapidly publish messages to my server via Websockets. For each message the server gets I store it in the form "timestamp: message" in my HashMap. I need HashMaps for returning the history of messages in chronological order with the timestamp needed. (Any other data structure recommendation is welcome.)

It so happens that when I rapidly publish messages, two or more messages have the same timestamp and hence I cannot save them. I'm already using `System.currentTimeMillis()`. I cannot go into Nanoseconds are I read the value is arbitrary and often unreliable.

I have tried appending a static `AtomicInteger` variable at the end of the timestamps and it works but, when I return the messages to my user I need to return a JSON and again I'm not able to store duplicate key.

How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: sorry moved it to an answer because it got too long ;)

Comment: Use `System.nanoTime()`. Although note that _Differences in successive calls that span greater than approximately 292 years ... will not correctly compute_.(?!)

Comment: I wish that was reliable. But, it's not.

Comment: Timestamp as a unique attribute itself might be unreliable and bound to clashes

Comment: @BoristheSpider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime Please read this. I need time from a reliable point, not some arbitrary value.

Comment: @PopoFibo that is the problem. What can be done?

Comment: @OP I know that. Your question does not make it clear that you need a timestamp for any other purpose than the key. Please edit your question to explain your use case.

Comment: I have mentioned that I need to maintain chronological order. That should suffice.

Comment: @GauravBhor in order to maintain order all you need is to ensure that the value of the key is greater for a message received later. An incrementing counter would work for that. You do not mention that you need to actual time.

Comment: It's your system which defines a value as duplicate, you may check the  combination of the message content and timestamp for uniqueness. If it fails, then you are in fact producing duplicates.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I need the timestamp to return the messages in chronological order as history. And I have already tried using a counter.

Comment: "I have mentioned that I need to maintain chronological order" then a counter will do exactly that.

Comment: actually, you dont even need a counter, you could just use a FIFO queue

Comment: And why don't you use `currentTimeMillis`, appended by `nanoTime`?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I really need to try that. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you need an absolute timestamp? maybe a counter - i.e. knowing `a` arrived before `b` - is enough, have a counter which you increment when a message arrives and use that as your 'timestamp'. no more duplicates and the chronological order is still intact.

furthermore, you could also just use a FIFO queue if you do not insist on having a map. this will also keep chronological order.

Comment: I need the timestamp :)

Comment: Separation of concerns - use a generic ID for your HashMap, and the timestamp as part of your business object in the map's values.

Comment: I finally ended up storing the messages in the format `{timestamp+count: "Message"}` Marking this as the write answer for helping me lead to it.