# Nano and milliseconds

Tags: java, time, nanotime

```
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    long startTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();

    M = app.decriptare_simpla(C);

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long stopTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();

    //mesajul initial dupa decriptare
    System.out.println("M : " + M.toString());
    System.out.println("Decriptarea a durat: " + (endTime - startTime));
    System.out.println("Decriptarea a durat: " + (stopTimer - startTimer));
```

This gave me:

```
Decriptarea a durat: 14811776
Decriptarea a durat: 15
```

What I want to ask is how much of a second are those 2 numbers? I mean are they, 0.15, 0.015, 0.0015...? I'd like to print them in that manner, not as an `long` but don't know how many decimals to add. Same question for the other number.

Comment: one second = 1,000 milliseconds = 1,000,000 microseconds = 1,000,000,000 nanoseconds

Comment: Refer to Wikipedia or elsewhere for the definition of the `milli-` and `nano-` prefix. Java did not invent them.

Comment: Ah, so I should just add 3 and 9 decimals. I see. Thought they had a different meaning than the realtime ones.

Comment: And keep in mind that the name "nanoTime" is deceptive. Depending on your operating system it will give different precision between several tens to several hundreds of nanoseconds.

Comment: Actually, the *precision* of the value returned by nanoTime is always the same -- billionths of seconds.  The *accuracy* can vary, i.e., not all systems have a clock that counts individual nanoseconds, and so the clock might only tick on 100 or 1000 nanoseconds and you will only ever get multiples of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The conversions follow the usual rules for [Standard SI Units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_prefix#List_of_prefixes):

```
long nanoSeconds = ...
double microSeconds = nanoSeconds / 1e3;
double milliSeconds = microSeconds / 1e3;
double seconds = milliSeconds / 1e3;

// Shortcuts:
double milliSeconds = nanoSeconds / 1e6;
double sconds = nanoSeconds / 1e9;
```

For some conversions, you can also have a look at the [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) class: It allows conversions between values in different time units, for example

```
long microSeconds = NANOSECONDS.toMicros(nanoSeconds);
```

However, it unfortunately does not allow time spans given in `double` precision, but only as `long` values.

---

An aside, also mentioned in the comments: Measuring time spans in the order of 10-15ms usually makes no sense due to the limited resolution of the internal timer.

Comment: So I should just use `System.time.millis` instead of nano?

Comment: It depends on your system.  I would be surprised if most general-purpose computers had clocks that measured nanoseconds accurately, and in fact most PC-style machines used to only tick at 10 millisecond intervals.  Keep in mind, too, that nanoseconds will overflow a long int much faster.

Comment: @rcook A time difference measured in nanoseconds will overflow after appx. 290 years, so this should not be an issue. Possibly interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this

```
System.out.println(TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert((endTime - startTime), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));
System.out.println(TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert((stopTimer - startTimer), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```