# How to Measuring performance in Java

Tags: java

How does one measure the performance of a method/period of time in an application in Java? Is there a class made specifically for this functionality?

Comment: Well how do you define "performance"? Now measure this definition. If you're talking about time to execute: `System.nanoTime()` is usually recommended over `System.currentTimeMillis()`, but that's as specific an answer as you can get.

Comment: Like in seconds, not asymptoptic analysis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

- Testing at design time. This means, you will perform your tests when designing the application. You may be tempted to create some methods and naively measure them by using `System.nanoTime()` (or, in worst case, `System.currentTimeMillis()`), and this is a naive approach because you're missing lot of concepts for handling a micro benchmark. Still, if you want to manually benchmark your methods, at least follow [proper rules for a micro benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/1065197). IMO you should not reinvent the wheel, instead use a benchmark framework like [JUnitBenchmarks](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/junit-benchmarks.html) or [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/) where you can measure the time of your algorithms/methods using unit testing.
- Testing at run time. This means, you will measure the performance when the application is running, usually in a dedicated environment similar to production environment. For this scenario, use a [profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)). There are lot of profilers for Java applications, from free license like [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) and [Java Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html) (this comes from JDK 7 u40) that are shipped in the JDK distribution to commercial products like [Yourkit](http://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/).

Answer (score 1):

In Java8, there is a new tool for this, have a look at http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/

> JMH is a Java harness for building, running, and analysing nano/micro/milli/macro benchmarks written in Java and other languages targetting the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.currentTimeMillis() or System.nanoTime() to get the time before and after the execution of the code you want to measure.

A more sofisticated approach would be to use [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) or a similar app for generating statistics of many executions.

An even more sofisticated approach would be to use [Perf4j](http://perf4j.codehaus.org/).

Comment: [`System.nanoTime()` is advised over `System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime).

Comment: *You can use System.currentTimeMillis() to get the time before and after the execution of the code* it would be better using [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())

Comment: AFAIK JMeter works for web based applications, doesn't work for desktop or console apps.

Comment: You can implement listeners that invoke many kinds of apps.

Comment: Also, this doesn't work well since it is a micro benchmark. Follow the [proposed rules for good microbenchmarking](http://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/1065197).

Comment: Perf4j project seems abandoned since year 2011...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this http://metrics.codahale.com/ and it rocks. It comes packaged in DropWizard which is nice. Also pick up a profiler -> yourKit or JMC (free Java Mission Control).

The key is to be lightweight when profiling. You don't want to add too much bias to the equation.