# Is System.CurrentTimeMillis accurate enough to ping a server?

Tags: java, time, ping

If I understand correctly, [System.currentTimeMillis()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) is faster, and [System.nanoTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--) is more accurate.

If I am pinging a server, which in worst case I expect to take...lets go extreme...one minute, is [System.currentTimeMillis()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) still going to be accurate within 1-2 milliseconds?  Or should I go with [System.nanoTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--)?

I am pinging the server like so:

```
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    getResponseFromServer();
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    return endTime - startTime;
```

As you can see, I am currently using [System.nanoTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--), but am unsure if I should be using [System.currentTimeMillis()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--).

[System.currentTimeMillis vs System.nanoTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime) has a lot of great information on the subject, but not specifics on accuracy of [System.currentTimeMillis()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--).

Comment: You're executing a blocking operation that might tak 1 minute, and are concerned about the performance of nanoTime(), which runs in microseconds (i.e. it runs millions of time faster than the ping). Why?

Comment: My objective is just to get the ping accurately.  I don't care about the blocking.  (Maybe because I don't know any better...)

Comment: Then since you know that nanoTime is more accurate, why do you care about its performance? Just use it: it will be fast enough.

Comment: @JBNizet I do still care about speed.  I wish I could better explain myself, but I don't quite understand what I am trying to do either :-) But nanoTime it is.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "get the ping accurately"? As pointed out, the ping operation itself can last from a few seconds to more than a minute. Does it really matter when exactly you trigger an operation which will end in 1, 5, 60 seconds?

Comment: @EddyG Maybe I am wrong on my terminology.  By ping, I want to know the time in milliseconds it takes to get the status code of my server.

Comment: OK, so what you actually want to do is to measure the time that it takes from sending something and receiving an answer? Then milli second precision should still be good enough; as in any real world scenario, you are talking about seconds. If you want to use nanos; fine - but that doesn't change the fact that this seems to be "overkill". And worse: because of the fact that there will be many many nanos for your "pings", it gets **much** harder to interpret the corresponding data. You are complicating your statistics for no good reason!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your OS, `currentTimeMillis()` may have a resolution of up to 15 milliseconds (Windows). On the other hand, the resolution of `nanoTime()` is about a microsecond on Linux/Mac and its latency is in the tens of nanoseconds. So when you say that `nanoTime()` is "slow", make sure you understand the actual scale of that qualification.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime is my source with 139 upvotes.  Maybe I misread.    Thanks!  Also, what does "resolution of up to 30 ms" mean?

Comment: A resolution of 30 ms means that two consecutive calls to that method will never report a difference of less than 30 ms.