# Java, getting length of time that a key is pressed, currentTimeMillies() is always 24

Tags: java, time, keylistener

I am making a code for a robot that will return to its original position when hit. To do so I am recording the amount of time that a key is pressed.

```
            switch (key) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                // System.out.println("UP pressed");
                // state = "";
                pressCount += 1;
                xTimeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
                myFinch.setWheelVelocities(255, 255);
                myFinch.setLED(0, 0, 255);
                // tempDistance = 1;
                break;
            }
```

That is for when the key is pressed, xTimeStart records the time at which the button is first pressed.

```
        switch (key) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            // System.out.println("UP released");
            xTimeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(xTimeEnd-xTimeStart);
            pressCount = 0;
            // tempDistance = 1;
            break;
       }
```

As you can see, I retrieve the time when the button is released and print out the difference between the two. Without dividing by 1000 or converting to seconds, the outcome is always around 24 (ranges from 23-25).

Help would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance :D.

Comment: Why not use a utility class like Guava's `Stopwatch`? For more precision  you should base your code on [`nanoTime`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/351565/589259).

Comment: Even with Stopwatch/nanoTime the resolution is bound by the event listeners which is limited by the operating system's UI message pump. You can get a more precise value, but not a more accurate one..

Comment: Two part of your code, the case value are both `KeyEvent.VK_UP` ?

Comment: yes. one is for when the up button is pressed and the second is for when it is released