# Accurate countdown?

Tags: java, android, performance, oop, optimization

I want to see if the user completed a certain task in one second. I know that there are several ways to get time elapsed, but I am wondering what the most accurate way would be for this scenario. I want to get time elapsed ever since a certain time. For example, register a timer, and refer back to it later:

1. User does something
2. I check if user completed task in the one second timer
3. User does something again
4. I check if the user completed the task within the same one second timer that was running before. If not, make timer null.
5. User does something again
6. I check if user completed the task within one second timer. If not, make timer null.

I want to basically have one timer that runs for one second, as the user completes various tasks. After every task, I check whether or not the timer is still going. I don't want to use countdowntimer for this, as it is not accurate enough for one second. What method can I use for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `System.nanoTime()`, if you need a nanosecond precision. I guess, `System.currentTimeMillis()` precision should be enough for your case.

Record a timestamp just before starting a task, then just after completing a task and task a difference.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/351571) for explanation  which method is better suits for you.

Comment: I have tried that, but my problem is that I am doing all of this in a listener which is in a separate class. Whenever it starts listening again, my timestamp variable that I had recorded earlier gets erased, and I get null when I try to use it. How do I prevent this variable (double) from losing its data?

Answer (score 0):

Use [System.nanoTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) if you want the highest precission. System.currentTimeMillis() should work for you too though.

> This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as that of currentTimeMillis().

Just implement a simple timer using either of these methods.

```
private static final class Timer {

    private long start;
    private long end;

    static double toSeconds(long nanos) {
        return nanos / 1000000000.0;
    }

    void start() {
        end = -1;
        start = System.nanoTime();
    }

    double getCurrent() {
        return toSeconds(System.nanoTime() - start);
    }

    double stop() {
        end = System.nanoTime();
        return toSeconds(end - start); 
    }

    boolean isRunning() {
        return end == -1;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.start();
    doSomething();
    if (timer.getCurrent() > 1.0) {
        double time = timer.stop();
        System.out.println("User completed task 1 in " + time);
    }

    doSomething();
    if (timer.isRunning() && timer.getCurrent() > 1.0) {
        double time = timer.stop();
        System.out.println("User completed task 1 & 2 in " + time);
    }

    doSomething();
    if (timer.isRunning() && timer.getCurrent() > 1.0) {
        double time = timer.stop();
        System.out.println("User completed task 1 & 2 & 3 in " + time);
    }

    System.out.println("All tasks finished");

}
```

Comment: I have tried that, but my problem is that I am doing all of this time recording in a listener which is in a separate class. Whenever it starts listening again, my timestamp variable that I had recorded earlier gets erased, and I get null when I try to use it. How do I prevent this variable (double) from losing its data?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to say without knowing the code.
Maybe you can check whether it's already recording the time?

Comment: Depends on your code; maybe you can update the question?