# I need to make my timers synchronized

Tags: java, android, timer

My question is for an Androip App. I am planning to use several timers and they will change the textviews' values once per second. But when I use `CountDownTimer`, textviews become unsynchronized. How can I create an exact timer that won't delay and I can see every textview change at the same time?

Comment: change every textview in the same timer. For example, create an object with a list for your textview and a timer. With the timer, proceed the list.

Comment: But my major problem is timer doesn't tick every exact 1 second. It ticks late or earlier sometimes and after an hour it has a difference like 9-10 seconds. I mean is there a different method without delays ?

Comment: Timers depending on how you use your cpu. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime

Comment: I tried to use nanoTime() but i need to setText() after 1 second. When I tried to execute my app naturally It tried to setText() for every nanosecond and just freezed. I couldn't find the way to make it per second instead of per nanosecond.

Comment: use 1000000000 factor (1000000000ns = 1s)

Comment: Not like this I mean I used It like

while(finish>start)
a.setText(currenttime);

Comment: You've seen/tested my answer at bottom?

Comment: Aded code tags, fixed some grammar (that I'd understand), added code tags.

Answer (score -1):

Create a timer in a thread like this:

```
for(;;){
long startTime = System.nanoTime();    
while(System.nanoTime() - startTime<1000000000){//1000000000ns = 1s
    //Wait or sleep(0)
}
System.out.println("Action!");//Call your action here
}
```