# Process im trying to calculate running time is executing in 0 nanoseconds. how?

Tags: java, performance, time, time-complexity

Im trying to calculate my algorithm performance. Basically my algorithm solves set operations such as union, disjuction, intersection etc. My algorithm can done this operations in O(logn) to compare with similar algorithms i implement a primitive aproach to solution, [blooms filter algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), Sorted List but when i tried to calculate running time i saw some of the operations in other algorithm takes literally 0(zero) nanosecond to complite. By the operation i mean finding union of two set each has 10000 element in it. How is that possible? you can see my project on [Github](https://github.com/OmerKayaa/FN_Algorithm).
Part that i calculate running time is at the test package

I've tried to use Jprofilier to make sure it all running on one thread

I've tried to debug between to time intervals to make sure its not neglecting calculation and finds correct results

```
static Duration IntersectDocumentsTime(AlgorithmInterface algorithm)
{
        Instant start = Instant.now(); // Time before calulation i tryed to put breakpoint here
        algorithm.IntersectDocuments(); // returns Term[] result of elements after union operation
        Instant end = Instant.now(); // Time after calulation
        return Duration.between(start,end); // i put a breakpoint here to see if IntersectDocuments() result is correct and actually calculated
}
```

This is how i print result

```
for (AlgorithmInterface al: Algorithms)
        {
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Algorithm: "+al.getClass().toString()+"\tOperation: Union\nTime: "
                    +OperationsInterface.AddDocumentsTime(al).toNanos()+"\tseconds");
            System.out.println("Algorithm: "+al.getClass().toString()+"\tOperation: Disjuction\nTime: "
                    +OperationsInterface.DisjointDocumentsTime(al).toNanos()+"\tseconds");
            System.out.println("Algorithm: "+al.getClass().toString()+"\tOperation: Intersection\nTime: "
                    +OperationsInterface.IntersectDocumentsTime(al).toNanos()+"\tseconds");
            System.out.println("Algorithm: "+al.getClass().toString()+"\tOperation: Subtraction\nTime: "
                    +OperationsInterface.SubtractDocumentsTime(al).toNanos()+"\tseconds");
            System.out.println("Algorithm: "+al.getClass().toString()+"\tOperation: Find\nTime: "
                    +OperationsInterface.ContainsTermTime(al,new Term("A")).toNanos()+"\tseconds");
        }
System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
```

Result looks like this

---

> Algorithm: class Algorithms.FNA.FNA    Operation: Union
>   Time: 1851133600    seconds
>   Algorithm: class Algorithms.FNA.FNA Operation: Disjuction
>   Time: 1799607700    seconds
>   Algorithm: class Algorithms.FNA.FNA Operation: Intersection
>   Time: 291703600 seconds
>   Algorithm: class Algorithms.FNA.FNA Operation: Subtraction
>   Time: 1022775100    seconds
>   Algorithm: class Algorithms.FNA.FNA Operation: Find
>   Time: 1319100   seconds

---

> Algorithm: class Algorithms.Primitive.Primitive    Operation: Union
>   Time: 81257800  seconds
>   Algorithm: class Algorithms.Primitive.Primitive Operation: Disjuction
>   Time: 85717600  seconds
>   Algorithm: class Algorithms.Primitive.Primitive Operation: Intersection
>   Time: 0 seconds
>   Algorithm: class Algorithms.Primitive.Primitive Operation: Subtraction
>   Time: 66472900  seconds
>   Algorithm: class Algorithms.Primitive.Primitive Operation: Find
>   Time: 0 seconds

---

> Algorithm: class Algorithms.BloomsFilter.BloomsFilter  Operation: Union
>   Time: 998900    seconds
>   Algorithm: class Algorithms.BloomsFilter.BloomsFilter   Operation: Disjuction
>   Time: 0 seconds
>   Algorithm: class Algorithms.BloomsFilter.BloomsFilter   Operation: Intersection
>   Time: 503800    seconds
>   Algorithm: class Algorithms.BloomsFilter.BloomsFilter   Operation: Subtraction
>   Time: 0 seconds
>   Algorithm: class Algorithms.BloomsFilter.BloomsFilter   Operation: Find
>   Time: 1312900   seconds

---

> Algorithm: class Algorithms.SortedList.SortedList  Operation: Union
>   Time: 0 seconds
>   Algorithm: class Algorithms.SortedList.SortedList   Operation: Disjuction
>   Time: 3721800   seconds
>   Algorithm: class Algorithms.SortedList.SortedList   Operation: Intersection
>   Time: 0 seconds
>   Algorithm: class Algorithms.SortedList.SortedList   Operation: Subtraction
>   Time: 810500    seconds
>   Algorithm: class Algorithms.SortedList.SortedList   Operation: Find
>   Time: 1173200   seconds

---

Comment: Mandatory read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Instant.now()` will be using the current time in milliseconds. Digging in to the code you can see it uses `System.currentTimeMillis()`. 
Instead of using the above approach you can use the following code where I have used the time in nano seconds.

```
static long IntersectDocumentsTime(AlgorithmInterface algorithm) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    algorithm.IntersectDocuments();
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    long durationInNanos = end - start;
    return durationInNanos;
}
```

Comment: The reason is `Instant.now()` uses milli seconds. But here I have used the nano seconds and got the difference of it.

Answer (score 4):

Don't write the micro benchmark yourself, use [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) framework. This will ensure that you are avoiding the common pitfalls e.g. tiered compilation.

In your code:

```
Instant start = Instant.now(); 
algorithm.IntersectDocuments();
Instant end = Instant.now();
return Duration.between(start,end);
```

the `algorithm.IntersectDocuments()` could have been optimized away if it has no side effects.

Do note that `Instant.now()` uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` behind the scene which is [not suitable for calculating elapsed time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/351571/1602555).

Comment: Does the method has any side effects? Could it be pre-calculated and inlined into a no-op? It's most likely clock drift from `Instant.now()` which uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` but it's a guess.