# Why is a ternary operator with two constants faster than one with a variable?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, conditional-operator

In Java, I have two different statements which accomplish the same result through using ternary operators, which are as follows:

1. `num < 0 ? 0 : num;`
2. `num * (num < 0 ? 0 : 1);`

It appears that the second statement is unnecessarily complex and would take longer than the first, however when I recorded the time that each took, using the following code, the results were as follows:

```
final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

Random rand = new Random();
float[] results = new float[100000000];
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    float num = (rand.nextFloat() * 2) - 1;
    results[i] = num < 0 ? 0 : num;
    //results[i] = num * (num < 0 ? 0 : 1);
}

final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Total Time: " + (endTime - startTime));
```

1. 1.232 seconds
2. 1.023 seconds 
   (Each averaged over 5 runs)

Why is there this significant speedup when using the second statement? It seems to include an unnecessary multiplication and have the same comparison. Does the first create a branch whilst the second does not?

Comment: Hey! Could you share details about how you've recorded the runtimes?

Comment: Post a complete working example so we can verify your results.

Comment: I have edited the code to show both the timing method (System.currentTimeMillis()) and my complete code.

Comment: I wonder what tricky optimization is getting you here to obscure the result. I bet if you ran it through something like JMH the results might look a little different.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem in Java but I can't reproduce it using C++.

Comment: I got similar results. Using `-Djava.compiler=NONE` multiplication was still faster (255503vs258628, total of 10 tries). This was probably just noise, but is still strange since the bytecode for multiplication loads num 2 times, actually pushes 1 and 0 as ints before converting them to floats (the other just pushes a float 0) and multiplies the values, it is a few instructions longer no matter what the path. Branches seem identical.

Comment: I've made another observation: When you change one of the result integers to `float` in `num * (num < 0 ? 0 : 1);`, e.g. `0f` or `1f`, the statement becomes as slow as the other.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, let's rewrite the benchmark with [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) to avoid [common benchmarking pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java).

```
public class FloatCompare {

    @Benchmark
    public float cmp() {
        float num = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextFloat() * 2 - 1;
        return num < 0 ? 0 : num;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public float mul() {
        float num = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextFloat() * 2 - 1;
        return num * (num < 0 ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

JMH also suggests that the multiplication code is a way faster:

```
Benchmark         Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
FloatCompare.cmp  avgt    5  12,940 ± 0,166  ns/op
FloatCompare.mul  avgt    5   6,182 ± 0,101  ns/op
```

Now it's time to engage [perfasm profiler](http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.com/2015/07/jmh-perfasm.html) (built into JMH) to see the assembly produced by JIT compiler. Here are the most important parts of the output (comments are mine):

`cmp` method:

```
  5,65%  │││  0x0000000002e717d0: vxorps  xmm1,xmm1,xmm1  ; xmm1 := 0
  0,28%  │││  0x0000000002e717d4: vucomiss xmm1,xmm0      ; compare num < 0 ?
  4,25%  │╰│  0x0000000002e717d8: jbe     2e71720h        ; jump if num >= 0
  9,77%  │ ╰  0x0000000002e717de: jmp     2e71711h        ; jump if num < 0
```

`mul` method:

```
  1,59%  ││  0x000000000321f90c: vxorps  xmm1,xmm1,xmm1    ; xmm1 := 0
  3,80%  ││  0x000000000321f910: mov     r11d,1h           ; r11d := 1
         ││  0x000000000321f916: xor     r8d,r8d           ; r8d := 0
         ││  0x000000000321f919: vucomiss xmm1,xmm0        ; compare num < 0 ?
  2,23%  ││  0x000000000321f91d: cmovnbe r11d,r8d          ; r11d := r8d if num < 0
  5,06%  ││  0x000000000321f921: vcvtsi2ss xmm1,xmm1,r11d  ; xmm1 := (float) r11d
  7,04%  ││  0x000000000321f926: vmulss  xmm0,xmm1,xmm0    ; multiply
```

The key difference is that there's no jump instructions in the `mul` method. Instead, conditional move instruction `cmovnbe` is used.

`cmov` works with integer registers. Since `(num < 0 ? 0 : 1)` expression uses integer constants on the right side, JIT is smart enough to emit a conditional move instead of a conditional jump.

In this benchmark, conditional jump is very inefficient, since [branch prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/3448419) often fails due to random nature of numbers. That's why the branchless code of `mul` method appears faster.

If we modify the benchmark in a way that one branch prevails over another, e.g by replacing

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextFloat() * 2 - 1
```

with

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextFloat() * 2 - 0.1f
```

then the branch prediction will work better, and `cmp` method will become as fast as `mul`:

```
Benchmark         Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
FloatCompare.cmp  avgt    5  5,793 ± 0,045  ns/op
FloatCompare.mul  avgt    5  5,764 ± 0,048  ns/op
```

Comment: Wouldn't calculating the random numbers before the benchmark lead to more accurate results? I'm asking here because when I tried it, it seemed the random number generation required more time then the difference measured and you seem to know the subject.

Comment: @Harpistry I intentionally replaced `Random` with `ThreadLocalRandom`, as the latter has significantly lower overhead. But you're right - precomputing random numbers would be even better.

Answer (score 4):

I have not investigated the code generated by the java compiler or the JIT generator, but when writing compilers, I usually detect and optimize ternary operators that perform boolean to integer conversions: `(num < 0 ? 0 : 1)` converts the boolean value to one of 2 integer constants. In C this particular code could be rewritten as `!(num < 0)`. This conversion can produce branchless code, which would beat the branching code generated for `(num < 0 ? 0 : num)` on modern CPUs, even with an additional multiplication opcode. Note however that it is rather easy to produce branchless code for `(num < 0 ? 0 : num)` too, but the java compiler / JIT generator might not.

Comment: @Dhiraj:thak you for your suggestion, but I meant a different idea: I wrote several compilers for languages with a ternary operator and when such a construction is used with 2 constant expressions, I try and generate branchless code which is usually possible.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was trying to update the answer as per what I thought it meant. Thanks for updating it. Now it is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered what makes the second statement take longer, but I cannot explain why it happens, if that makes sense. That said, I do believe this should gives some greater insight into the issue we have here.

Before I explain my reasoning I'll just tell you my discoveries outright: This has nothing to do with returning a constant or a variable from a ternary operation. It has everything to do with returning an integer or a float from a ternary operation. It comes down to this: returning a float from a ternary operation is "significantly" slower than returning an integer.

I cannot explain why, but that is the root cause at least.

Here's my reasoning: I used the following code to create a small text document with results, very similar to your example code.

```java
        Random rand = new Random();
        final int intOne = 1;
        final int intZero = 0;
        final float floatOne = 1f;
        final float floatZero = 0f;

        final long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        float[] results = new float[100000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
            float num = (rand.nextFloat() * 2) - 1;
//            results[i] = num < 0 ? 0 : num;
//            results[i] = num * (num < 0 ? 0 : 1);

//            results[i] = num < 0 ? 0 : 1;
//            results[i] = (num < 0 ? 0 : 1);
//            results[i] = (num < 0 ? 0 : num);
//            results[i] = 1 * (num < 0 ? 0 : num);

//            results[i] = num < 0 ? 0 : one;
//            results[i] = num < 0 ? 0 : 1f;
//            results[i] = (num < 0 ? 0 : one);
//            results[i] = (num < 0 ? 0 : 1f);
//            results[i] = (num < 0 ? 0 : 1);

//            results[i] = (num < 0 ? 0f : 1f);
//            results[i] = (num < 0 ? 0 : 1);
//            results[i] = (num < 0 ? floatZero : floatOne);
//            results[i] = (num < 0 ? intZero : intOne);

//            results[i] = num < 0 ? intZero : intOne;

//            results[i] = num * (num < 0 ? 0 : 1);
//            results[i] = num * (num < 0 ? 0f : 1f);
//            results[i] = num < 0 ? 0 : num;
        }

        final long endTime = System.nanoTime();

        String str = (endTime - startTime) + "\n";
        System.out.println(str);
        Files.write(Paths.get("test.txt"), str.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

For reasons I won't go into now but you can read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime), I used `nanoTime()` instead of `currentTimeMillis()`. The last line just adds the resulting time value to a text document so i can easily add comments.

Here's the final text document, it includes the entire process of how I came to this conclusion:

```
    num < 0 ? 0 : num       // standard "intuitive" operation
    1576953800
    1576153599
    1579074600
    1564152100
    1571285399
    
    num * (num < 0 ? 0 : 1)    // strange operation that is somehow faster
    1358461100
    1347008700
    1356969200
    1343784400
    1336910000
    
    // let's remove the multiplication and focus on the ternary operation
    
    num < 0 ? 0 : 1     // without the multiplication, it is actually slower...?
    1597369200
    1586133701
    1596085700
    1657377000
    1581246399
    
    (num < 0 ? 0 : 1)     // Weird, adding the brackets back speeds it up
    1797034199
    1294372700
    1301998000
    1286479500
    1326545900
    
    (num < 0 ? 0 : num)     // adding brackets to the original operation does NOT speed it up.
    1611220001
    1585651599
    1565149099
    1728256000
    1590789800
    
    1 * (num < 0 ? 0 : num)    // the speedup is not simply from multiplication
    1588769201
    1587232199
    1589958400
    1576397900
    1599809000
    
    // Let's leave the return value out of this now, we'll just return either 0 or 1.
    
    num < 0 ? 0 : one  // returning 1f, but from a variable
    1522992400
    1590028200
    1605736200
    1578443700
    1625144700
    
    num < 0 ? 0 : 1f   // returning 1f as a constant
    1583525400
    1570701000
    1577192000
    1657662601
    1633414701
    
    // from the last 2 tests we can assume that returning a variable or returning a constant has no significant speed difference.
    // let's add the brackets back and see if that still holds up.
    
    (num < 0 ? 0 : floatOne)  // 1f as variable, but with ()
    1573152100
    1521046800
    1534993700
    1630885300
    1581605100
    
    (num < 0 ? 0 : 1f)  // 1f as constant, with ()
    1589591100
    1566956800
    1540122501
    1767168100
    1591344701
    // strangely this is not faster, where before it WAS. The only difference is that I now wrote 1f instead of 1.
    
    (num < 0 ? 0 : 1)  // lets replace 1f with 1 again, then.
    1277688700
    1284385000
    1291326300
    1307219500
    1307150100
    // the speedup is back!
    // It would seem the speedup comes from returning an integer rather than a float. (and also using brackets around the operation.. somehow)
    
    // Let's try to confirm this by replacing BOTH return values with floats, or integers.
    // We're also keeping the brackets around everything, since that appears to be required for the speedup
    
    (num < 0 ? 0f : 1f)
    1572555600
    1583899100
    1595343300
    1607957399
    1593920499
    
    (num < 0 ? 0 : 1)
    1389069400
    1296926500
    1282131801
    1283952900
    1284215401
    
    // looks promising, now lets try the same but with variables
    // final int intOne = 1;
    // final int intZero = 0;
    // final float floatOne = 1f;
    // final float floatZero = 0f;
    
    (num < 0 ? floatZero : floatOne)
    1596659301
    1600570100
    1540921200
    1582599101
    1596192400
    
    (num < 0 ? intZero : intOne)
    1280634300
    1300473900
    1304816100
    1285289801
    1286386900
    
    // from the looks of it, using a variable or constant makes no significant difference, it definitely has to do with the return type.
    
    // That said, this is still only noticeable when using brackets around the operation, without them the int operation is still slow:
    
    num < 0 ? intZero : intOne
    1567954899
    1565483600
    1593726301
    1652833999
    1545883500
    
    // lastly, lets add the multiplication with num back, knowing what we know now.
    
    num * (num < 0 ? 0 : 1)    // the original fast operation, note how it uses integer as return type.
    1379224900
    1333161000
    1350076300
    1337188501
    1397156600
    
    results[i] = num * (num < 0 ? 0f : 1f)  // knowing what we know now, using floats should be slower again.
    1572278499
    1579003401
    1660701999
    1576237400
    1590275300
    // ...and it is.
    
    // Now lets take a look at the intuitive solution
    
    num < 0 ? 0 : num      // the variable num is of type float. returning a float from a ternary operation is slower than returning an int.
    1565419400
    1569075400
    1632352999
    1570062299
    1617906200
```

This all still begs the question: *Why is a ternary operation that returns a float slower than one returning an int?* Both an int and float are 32 bits. Without the ternary operation floats are not particularly slow, we can see that because we can multiply the returned int with a float variable, and that does not slow it down. I do not have the answer to that.

As for why the brackets speed up the operation: I am no expert, but I'm guessing it probably has to do with the compiler slowing down the code by doing what *should* be an optimization:

```
results[i] = num < 0 ? 0 : 1;
```

Here the compiler sees `results` is an array of type float and simply replaces the integers with floats as an "optimization", this way it doesn't have to convert between types.

```
results[i] = (num < 0 ? 0 : 1);
```

Here the brackets force the interpreter to compute everything within them before doing anything else, this results in an int. Only AFTER that will the result be converted to a float so that it can fit in the array, type conversion isn't slow at all.

Again, I have no technical knowledge to back this up, it is only my educated guess.

Hopefully this is a good enough answer, if not at least it should point people with more technical knowledge than me in the right direction.