# How to profile execution time of methods in a JUnit Test in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, profiling

I have some component tests that are running relatively slow (a few seconds each) and am trying to figure out which functions are eating the most time. Is there a way I can have that displayed to me in eclipse when I run a JUnit test, maybe similar to the coverage data?

I have already tried using VisualVM for that, but the problem I have there is that the test process is only available while the test is running, so the best I can do there is put a breakpoint right at the beginning of the test, then debug the test, attach the VisualVM profiler, and the unpause the test, which sadly means that whatever few seconds I need to unpause the test bloats up the statistic.

It feels like there should be some way to say "start test and profile method execution time", but I have been looking at a few different options now (such as the Java Monitor plugin for eclipse) but none of them seems to offer that option?

Is there a way to do that? Or is it really the best solution to pause each test and then manually attach a profiler?

And maybe related to this, if I have a test case suite, how do I attach the profiler before any tests are run?

Comment: I've always used JProfiler with Eclipse and never ran into a problem of attaching the profiler, having to hit the correct instance and so on. You might want to give it a try over VisualVM.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff : Seems interesting, but how do I get it to work in Eclipse? I installed and integrated it, started eclipse with -clean, enabled the profile-action, but for some reason there is no available action if I right-click on a test and say `Profile as...`, and I can't figure out how to add a profiling configuration either. I would expect there to be a `Profile as... > JUnit Test` or maybe `Profile as... > JProfiler` to be available, but there isn't.

Comment: Sorry, I don't recall the steps I had to take with Eclipse. In my Eclipse, there is `Profile as... > JUnit Test` in the context menu, and then it starts JProfiler. In Window / Preferences, have you set the JProfiler executable .EXE location?

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff : For me the only option under "Profile as..." is "Profile on Server", which doesn't seem to do anything, and adding a new Profiling configuration also seems to only add new Server stuff. What do you mean with "JProfiler executable .EXE location"? I've looked through the `Window.Preferences`, but I can't find a setting for this. Do I need to have an additional plugin installed? When installing JProfiler I did integrate it with Eclipse, but come to think of it I can't see any indication that that integration worked.

Comment: Sorry, then I can't help any more, maybe some JProfiler support forum can answer that.

Answer (score -1):

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
//your code to measure the time of
long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

you can just print out estimatedTime and the part of your code that takes longest is the one that prints out the biggest number

[here are some more information on System.nanoTime() and System.currentTimeMillis() and the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime)