# Is there a way to calculate the time required to complete every completableFuture?

Tags: java, asynchronous, time, completable-future

Before I jump into the specifics of the question, I want to give the context of the problem. Basically, my code looks like

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    result = doSomething();
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    responseTime.add(endTime - startTime);
    results.add(result);
} 
print(results and responseTime);
```

Now what i want to do is run *doSomething()* as a completableFuture and get the responseTime as mentioned above. But since doing something like this would be totally incorrect --

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    resultCF = CompletableFuture.supplyasync(() -> doSomething());
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    responseTime.add(endTime - startTime);
    results.add(resultCF); //result is to store the completableFutures
}
CompletableFuture.allOf(results.toArray(new CompletableFuture[results.size()])).join();
print(i.get() for i in results and responseTimes);
```

since it would defeat the purpose of getting the execution time of each *doSomething()*. So, is there any way I can get the response time of each completableFuture? Also, i would need the results arraylist containing the completableFutures(*resultCF*) at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest may be to just add a stage to `resultCF`, which itself adds the response time to the list. `resultCF` will be completed after this part is done:

```
resultCF = CompletableFuture.supplyasync(() -> doSomething())
              .thenApply(s -> {
                  responseTime.add(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                  return s;
               });
results.add(resultCF);
```

Comment: `System::currentTimeMillis` is not a monotonic clock, meaning it is subject to arbitrary jumps when the system synchronizes its time. Therefore, it's not reliable for time deltas; for that, you can use `System::nanoTime`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18994289/7096763