# Multiple task but run concurrently in a separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm

I have encountered some challenge, I just want to confirm my knowledge is correct.

How are you going to implement this?

> For example, if your program is written in Java the Sieve of Eratosthenes testing should run in one thread, and the Brute Force testing should run concurrently in a separate thread. Finally, your program should report the results of the benchmarking to the screen and exit.

Is it Something like this?

```
class TestMultitasking4{  
 public static void main(String args[]){  
  Thread t1=new Thread(){  
    public void run(){  
      System.out.println("task one");  
    }  
  };  
  Thread t2=new Thread(){  
    public void run(){  
      System.out.println("task two");  
    }  
  };  
  
  
  t1.start();  
  t2.start();  
 }  
}
```

Comment: yes, I think your code is correct

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct although you might want to avoid creating [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#syntax-of-anonymous-classes) by extending `Thread` inside the method.

The next step is to measure the elapsed time inside `Runnable` and use `Thread.join()` to wait for the threads to finish so you can display the results. Make sure to use the `System.nanoTime()` method and not `currentTimeMillis()` [see here why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/351571/1602555).

If you feel like exploring Java standard library further take a look at things in the `java.util.concurrent` package e.g. a [`java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect. If you run the program it will just start 2 threads and exit immediately because your main thread will not wait for the termination of t1 and t2.

You should:

- Collect the results of your threads (you need callable and futures)
- Wait for the threads to terminate (Thread.join is the primitive)

There are lots of ways to achieve this without using Threads directly  **using higher-level abstractions** . The simplest way is probably using [CompletableFuture](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture#Multiple)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture<Boolean> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> isPrime(42));
    CompletableFuture<String> future2 =  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> bruteForcePassword("encrypted"));

    var prime = future1.join();
    var pwd = future2.join();

    System.out.println("Was prime:" + prime);
    System.out.println("Password:" + pwd);
}

private static String bruteForcePassword(String s) {
    return "Alph@Rome0";
}

private static boolean isPrime(long value) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Actually, unless you do `t1.setDaemon(true);` or `t2.setDaemon(true);` the program will not exit before every thread has ended.