# How do I modify Kotlin Flow distinctUntilChanged to add an expiry time

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

How can I use `distinctUntilChanged()` but also add an expiry to it, which means if the same value is in the flow we still collect it because it was longer than `expiry` milliseconds after the previous duplicated value was emitted.

```
flow { 
  emit("A")    // printed
  emit("B")    // printed
  emit("A")    // printed
  emit("A")    // NOT printed because duplicate
  delay(5000)
  emit("A")    // printed because 5 seconds elapsed which is more than expiry
}
  .distinctUntilChanged(expiry = 2000)
  .collect {
    println(it)
  }
```

I would like this to print:

```
A
B
A
A
```

Here's the code to test it:

```
  @Test
  fun `distinctUntilChanged works as expected`(): Unit = runBlocking {
    flow {
      emit("A")    // printed
      emit("B")    // printed
      emit("A")    // printed
      emit("A")    // NOT printed because duplicate
      delay(5000)
      emit("A")    // printed because 5 seconds elapsed which is more than expiry
    }
      .distinctUntilChanged(expiry = 2000)
      .toList().also {
        assertEquals("A", it[0])
        assertEquals("B", it[1])
        assertEquals("A", it[2])
        assertEquals("A", it[3])
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this will work, but I didn't test very much. I think the logic is self-explanatory. The reason `havePreviousValue` exists is in case `T` is nullable and the first emitted value is `null`.

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.distinctUntilChanged(expiry: Long) = flow {
    var havePreviousValue = false
    var previousValue: T? = null
    var previousTime: Long = 0
    collect {
        if (!havePreviousValue || previousValue != it || previousTime + expiry < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            emit(it)
            havePreviousValue = true
            previousValue = it
            previousTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Since the code measures elapsed time, System.nanoTime() might be more appropriate if you want to isolate yourself from system clock adjustments https://stackoverflow.com/a/18994289/611819

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```kotlin
fun <T> Flow<T>.distinctUntilChanged(expiry: Long) = 
    merge(
        distinctUntilChanged(), 
        channelFlow {
            val shared = buffer(Channel.CONFLATED).produceIn(this)
            debounce(expiry).takeWhile { !shared.isClosedForReceive }.collect { 
                val lastVal = shared.receive()
                shared.receive().let { if(lastVal == it) send(it) }
            }
        }
    )
```

It basically adds back the non-distinct value to distinctUntilChanged().