# Java Instant.now returns millisecond accuracy when running on under Wine

Tags: java, time, wine

We're running a Java 11 windows application on a Centos 8 using Wine 6.

When we made the switch from Wine 4 to 6 we saw that `Instant.now` started to return values in Millisecond accuracy instead of nanos/micros.

One of our developers at the time was able to trace it to a specific function in wine code and apply a patch to reverse it.

Unfortunately that developer is long gone, and so is the patch :( And unfortunately I've no idea how to trace that change my self.

Now we want to migrate to Wine 8 but when we do that we still suffer from that accuracy issue, our application is very latency sensitive and we rely on microseconds accuracy for measurement.

Is anyone else familiar with that problem and has any idea how to fix it? We're building Wine from source so I'm down with anything.

Or maybe we should use something other than `Instant.now()` that is more portable?

Comment: Don't use `Instant` for measurements. Use `System.nanoTime()` instead which is guaranteed to be chronologically strictly increasing (`Instant.now()` can go "backwards", i.e. the latter of two measurements can give you a time before the former). You will not necessarily get a better precision, but it's worth a try. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime compares the two

Comment: If you don't care about the actual time, but rather *time differences*, then you could use `System.nanoTime()`.

Comment: You are confusing 'accuracy' with the number of digits in a value.

Comment: I need the number of microseconds since epoch, at the moment we're using `ChronoUnit.MICROS.between(Instant.EPOCH, Instant.now())`